# Obtain approximate Hessian using FindMinimum

Tags: matrix, numerics, mathematical-optimization

According to [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationQuasiNewtonMethods.html), when `FindMinimum` is told to use the method `"QuasiNewton"` on a unconstrained problem, it uses the BFGS approximation to the Hessian matrix of the function being optimized. How can I recover the Hessian matrix computed by Mathematica using `StepMonitor`, `EvaluationMonitor` or any other devious trick?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Unfortunately, this requires a lot more devious trickery than I would have preferred. As noted in the documentation at [`tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationQuasiNewtonMethods`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationQuasiNewtonMethods.html#1559622209), the Hessian is not formed directly in the BFGS method, so we have to recover it from the Cholesky factors. However, all of this is done inside the kernel where we cannot access it using ordinary methods, and the only way I can see to obtain these factors is to hook calls to the BLAS function [`*TRSV`](http://www.netlib.org/blas/dtrsv.f) (called as `` LinearAlgebra`BLAS`TRSV `` in *Mathematica*) and extract its arguments directly. Needless to say, this is hardly likely to be particularly robust, but it hopefully it will work well enough for your needs.

Let us define:

```
approximateHessianList[f_, vars_, start_] :=
  With[{fmarg2 = Thread[{vars, start}]},
   Module[{steps, lowerTriangles, upperTriangles},
    Internal`InheritedBlock[{LinearAlgebra`BLAS`TRSV},
     Unprotect[LinearAlgebra`BLAS`TRSV];
     trsv : LinearAlgebra`BLAS`TRSV[uplo_, trans_, diag_, a_, x_] /; (
       Switch[
        trans,
        "N", Sow[LowerTriangularize[a], "LowerTriangle"],
        "T", Sow[UpperTriangularize[a], "UpperTriangle"]
       ]; True
      ) := trsv;
     Protect[LinearAlgebra`BLAS`TRSV];
     {steps, lowerTriangles, upperTriangles} =
      Reap[
       FindMinimum[
        f, fmarg2,
        Method -> {"QuasiNewton", "StepMemory" -> Infinity},
        StepMonitor :> Sow[vars, "Step"]
       ], {"Step", "LowerTriangle", "UpperTriangle"}
      ][[2, {1, 2, 3}, 1]];
     Transpose[{steps, MapThread[Dot, {lowerTriangles, upperTriangles}]}]
    ]
   ]
  ];
SetAttributes[approximateHessianList, HoldAll];
```

We may now write:

```
approximateHessianList[Cos[x^2 - 3 y] + Sin[x^2 + y^2], {x, y}, {1, 1}]
```

which gives a list of steps in the BFGS optimization along with the approximate Hessians evaluated at those points. For the sake of brevity (and because it is obviously the most accurate), let us take only the last of these:

> ```
> {{1.37638, 1.67868}, {{15.1553, 0.986982}, {0.986982, 20.2017}}}
> ```

which we may compare to the exact Hessian evaluated at this point:

```
D[Cos[x^2 - 3 y] + Sin[x^2 + y^2], {{x, y}, 2}] /. {
  x -> 1.376384972443001`, y -> 1.6786760817546214`
 }
```

> ```
> {{15.1555, 0.983708}, {0.983708, 20.2718}}
> ```

Clearly, it is not a bad approximation.

Now, some caveats. Since the logic of the code inside the kernel is completely opaque, I am not sure whether this business with the upper and lower triangles is really necessary, since the argument `a` of `` LinearAlgebra`BLAS`TRSV `` appears to be the same for successive calls, firstly with `trans == "N"` and then with `trans == "T"`. However, this represents at most an inefficiency. A more serious problem is that I am not sure whether the first Hessian obtained using this method corresponds to the initial point, $(x,y)=(1,1)$ , or the point at the end of the first step, which here is $(x,y)=(0.811216, 1.68144)$ . While this does not really matter if the approximation has converged, it does influence the interpretation of the earlier approximations substantially, so hopefully someone with access to the kernel code will be able to clarify this aspect of `` FindMinimum`QuasiNewton ``'s behaviour.

Comment: I'd plus you 10,000 points if I could, Oleksandr. Can you elaborate briefly on the line which implements the hook? I haven't mastered all the ":" and "/;" tricks, and can't quite see what that line does. Brilliant work.

Comment: This is closely related to the [Villegas-Gayley trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5149656#5149656), but a little more concise when you don't need another `Block` (for example, if the definition is already inside an ``Internal`InheritedBlock``). Here we pattern match the function call (with a named pattern), and take advantage of a `Condition` containing `(code; True)` so that `code` executes (once only) each time the hooked function is called. The call proper is passed through the hook by means of the pattern name (here `trsv`).

Comment: This is insane!

Comment: I have to agree with @R.M, the insanity for me was `trsv: ... := trsv` to attach the hook.

Answer (score 12):

Using [`` Experimental`NumericalFunction `` framework](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44890/280) directly ([`FindMinimum` uses it under the hood](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25432/how-to-create-internally-optimized-expression-for-computing-with-high-workingpre#comment78937_25432)) it is straightforward to get the numerical approximation of the Hessian:

```
f = Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[{x, y}, 
   Cos[x^2 - 3 y] + Sin[x^2 + y^2], {1}, Hessian -> FiniteDifference];

f["Hessian"[{1.376384972443001`, 1.6786760817546214`}]]
```

> {{{15.1555, 0.983708}, {0.983708, 20.2718}}}

Comment: As far as Hessian is concerned, what are the other options apart from FiniteDifference? Thanks!

Comment: As explained in the [linked answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44890/280), `Hessian` takes three possible values: `Automatic`, `Symbolic` and `FiniteDifference` with `Automatic` being equivalent to `Symbolic` AFAIK.

Comment: @Alexey Popkov How is the scale chosen? Are finite differences adaptive? Is the Richardson extrapolation methodology used?

Comment: @Valerio Since ``Experimental`NumericalFunction`` is undocumented, we can only guess and experiment. You can create a separate question on it.

Comment: @Alexey Popkov I created a [new question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/173540/462) as you suggested.

Comment: Alexey, what's the {1}, in the definition of the function for?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea It is the dimensions of the output matrix produced by the expression, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44890/280).