# Using Apply inside Compile

Tags: programming, compile

In [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4877/745) great answer a compiled version of the [Nelder-Mead algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method) is presented.

Since it works on arbitrary dimensions (i.e. arbitrary number of arguments), it has to use apply on the objective function. The problem is that `Apply` is not directly supported inside `Compile`. To overcome this limitation the following code is used:

```
(* Produces compiled code for the Nelder-Mead algorithm with the objective function inlined *)
ClearAll[apply];
SetAttributes[apply, HoldAll];
apply[f : (_Function | _CompiledFunction), vars : {__Symbol}] :=
    With[{applied := f @@ vars},
      Function[arglist, Block[vars, vars = arglist; applied]]
     ];
```

This seems to work (inside the package), but I have no idea, how it works.

**Could somebody explain the techniques behind this code snippet?** Specifically:

- What does `SetDelayed` do inside `With`?
- Why does `vars` appear twice in the arguments to `Block`?
- Why doesn't this minimal example work? (I believe it mimics what is done in the mentioned answer...)

  ```
  Clear[a, b, c, x, y, z, objectiveFunction, cfunc];
  objectiveFunction = Compile[{a, b, c, x, y, z} ,
     (a - x)^2 + 50 (b - y)^2 + (c - z)^2];

  cfunc = With[{f = apply[objectiveFunction, {a, b, c, x, y, z}]},
    Compile[ {{pts, _Real, 1}}, f@pts]
    ]
  << CompiledFunctionTools`
  CompilePrint[cfunc]
  ```

**EDIT:**

Here is the working snippet. Note that  `"InlineCompiledFunctions"` must be set to `True` to avoid the call to `MainEvaluate`.

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, x, y, z, apply, objectiveFunction, cfunc];
(* Produces inlinable code for use inside Compile (where Apply is not \
supported directly) *)
SetAttributes[apply, HoldRest];
apply[f : (_Function | _CompiledFunction), vars : {__Symbol}] :=
       Function[arglist, Block[vars, vars = arglist; f @@ vars]];

objectiveFunction = Compile[{a, b, c, x, y, z} ,
   (a - x)^2 + 50 (b - y)^2 + (c - z)^2];
apply[objectiveFunction, {a, b, c, x, y, z}]
cfunc = With[{f = apply[objectiveFunction, {a, b, c, x, y, z}]},
  Compile[ {{pts, _Real, 1}}, f@pts,
    CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}]
  ]
<< CompiledFunctionTools`
CompilePrint[cfunc]
```

Comment: This makes me wonder why is the a system option called ApplyCompileLength and why is it set to Infinity

Comment: @Szabolcs This is an entirely different story. `Apply` as discussed here evaluates at (pre) `Compile`-time and is a tool of code generation. The option you mention governs the auto-compilation of `Apply`, when it would be explicitly present in the `Compile` body when auto-compiling. Since `Apply` is only supported for 3 heads (`List`, `Plus` and `Times`) by `Compile`, it does not generally make sense to set the mentioned option to a finite number. In case you have one of those heads, you can of course reset it.

Comment: @Leonid (It was really a question, not a comment...) Is it documented somewhere that it's supported for these three heads?  Do you know why that option is set to `Infinity`?

Comment: @Szabolcs It is documented, but I can't tell you where off hand. For the option setting, `Infinity` is equivalent to saying "don't attempt to auto-compile at all". The fact that only 3 heads are supported means that `Compile` *does not* generally support `Apply`, which is probably the reason for this setting. For those heads, it can be reset manually, as I mentioned.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First question : `With` accepts a syntax like

```
  With[{var:=value}, expression]
```

in which case, `value` is injected into expression unevaluated. As far as I know, this syntax is not documented. You can achieve a similar effect with the replacement rules, by using

```
Unevaluated[expression]/.HoldPattern[var]:>value
```

There are some subtle differences between the semantics of `With` and repalcement rules though, mostly related to the treatment of nested scoping constructs and variable name conflicts in them.

Second question: `vars` appear twice because they must first be `Block`-ed, and then there is a massive assignment to them performed in the body of the `Block`. This is probably the most economical way of blocking a number of variables and assigning values to them simultaneously - otherwise a more complex code-generation will be needed. You can see another example of that in   [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682742/optional-named-arguments-without-wrapping-them-all-in-optionvalue/4683924#4683924) (and if you look at the revision history for that answer, you can find an alternative, harder way to do this, in one of the previous revisions).

Third question: this does not work because the `apply` function was made `HoldAll` (which isn't quite necessary), and the pattern-matching does not work. There were some past discussions on this topic on SO, but can't find them right now. But I discussed this topic at length also in [my book](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node408.html). The idea is that at the pattern-matching time, all seen by `apply` is a variable `objectiveFunction`, and because it does not evaluate it, the pattern `_CompiledFunction` is not matched. The solution is to make `apply` `HoldRest`, and then it works:

```
ClearAll[apply];
SetAttributes[apply, HoldRest];
apply[...]:=...
```

Comment: Aha, so this works by wrapping the original function in another function which takes just a single argument (the list) and then mass assigning back to individual arguments? When is the `Apply` used in `With` evaluated?

Comment: Or to put it another way, why is `With` even necessary, since `apply[f : (_Function | _CompiledFunction), vars : {__Symbol}] :=
       Function[arglist, Block[vars, vars = arglist; f @@ vars]];` seems to work as well.

Comment: @Ajasja Only inside `Block`, and that's the entire point, because by that time, `Block` guarantees that the variables have no global values.

Comment: @Ajasja `With` isn't necessary. Your function is exactly equivalent. I suppose it was intended to make the code more readable.

Comment: Thanks, this was very instructive.

Comment: @Ajasja Glad to help, and thanks for the accept.

Comment: Leonid, many thanks for answering this, especially as it was arguably my responsibility to do so but I don't have time at the moment. I owe you one! (BTW, the `With` is just a remnant of a previous iteration of this function. Since it caused confusion, I should probably remove it in the posted answer.)

Comment: @OleksandrR. No problem :) You use some really nice stuff, which is a lot of fun to read and discuss. By the way, I take this opportunity to say that I am (among many others) quite impressed by that answer of yours which originated this question. I think we need more answers like that one, to show that one can often use Mathematica as an implementation language for some missing functionality, and that the absence or limitations of some built-in function don't mean that "Mathematica can not do this", or "can not do this fast enough". I think you did a great job proving such statements wrong.

Comment: That `SetDelayed`ish syntax in `With` is really useful. It's a shame it's not documented. +1!

Comment: @Pillsy Yes, it is useful, I agree.