# Using Goto and Label in compiled function?

Tags: bugs, compile

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier, persisting through 13.2 or later**

---

Below I post some rudimentary code to show that there is something wrong using Goto and Label commands in compiled functions (or I believe there is something wrong). It seems that the command Label is not found. Does anybody know what's going on?

```
toy=Compile[{{x,_Real}},
  Label["t"];
  y=RandomReal[{-1.,1.}];
  If[x*y<-0.,Print[y*x];Goto["t"],Print[y*x," ","done"]]
];

toy[1.]
(*Goto::nolabel: "Label ("t") not found.*)
```

Answer (score 6):

This one is weird, and by my understanding of things, it is a bug. `Label` and `Goto` are on the list of compilable functions, and in fact, if you make your function completely compilable (i.e. compilable to code that does not call `MainEvaluate`), there is no problem. For example, this works without a hitch:

```
toy = Compile[{{x, _Real}},
  c = 0;
  Label[t];
  c++;
  If[x*RandomReal[{-1., 1.}] < -0., Goto[t]];
  c]
```

In your original function, however, the print statements prevented the `Goto` to be compiled, and it stayed inside a call to `MainEvaluate`. `CompilePrint` says your function is compiled into:

```
2   V17 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{x}, y = RandomReal[{-1., 1.}]][ R0]]
3   R3 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{x}, y][ R0]]
4   R4 = R0 * R3
5   B0 = R4 < R5 (tol R6)
6   R4 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{x}, If[x y < 0., Print[y x]; Goto[t], Print[y x,  , done]]][ R0]]
```

**You see the `Goto` is still there, inside the `MainEvaluate` call, but the `Label` has been compiled away: thus, the warning that the label cannot be found.**

If you remove the print statement near the `Goto`, the `If` is compiled and `MainEvaluate` is called only on its second branch:

```
toy3 = Compile[{{x, _Real}},
   Label["t"];
   y = RandomReal[{-1., 1.}];
   If[x*y < -0., Goto["t"], Print[y*x, " ", "done"]]];
```

gives

```
2   V17 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{x}, y = RandomReal[{-1., 1.}]][ R0]]
3   R3 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{x}, y][ R0]]
4   R4 = R0 * R3
5   B0 = R4 < R5 (tol R6)
6   if[ !B0] goto 9
7   goto 2
8   goto 10
9   V17 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{x}, Print[y x,  , done]][ R0]]
```

which works fine too, because now both the `Label` and the `Goto` have been compiled.

---

The reason I call it a bug is that I don't see this limitation specified anywhere in the documentation. I suggest reporting it to Wolfram support.

Comment: The label is still there in both cases. The problem is that labels aren't shared between the VM and the main evaluator (which makes sense, as you can't jump into compiled code at an arbitrary point), so `Goto[t]` does not find its target. That the compiler can be tricked into divorcing a `Goto` from its corresponding `Label` probably is a bug, I guess stemming from an attempt to minimize the number of (expensive) calls back into the main evaluator.

Comment: I should mention as well that the performance of compiled code like this, peppered as it is with calls out of the VM, will be absolutely horrific. For example, a single `Ordering` call per iteration in an early version of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4877/312) consumed about 80% of the runtime--and that's with a fairly substantial loop body. The practical impact of this bug, then, will probably be minimal in most cases (as performance improvement is usually the main reason why one would use `Compile` in the first place).

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with `Label`. The problem is that print can not be compiled. (see the [list of compilable functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions)). Also `y` must be localized.

So compare

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
CompilePrint[toy]
```

which returns

```
        1 argument
        2 Boolean registers
        9 Real registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        R0 = A1
        R2 = 1.
        R6 = 7.
        R1 = -1.
        R7 = -0.6382060350723182
        R5 = 0.
        Result = R4

1   
2   V17 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{x}, y = RandomReal[{-1., 1.}]][ R0]]
3   R3 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{x}, y][ R0]]
4   R4 = R0 * R3
5   B0 = R4 < R5 (tol R6)
6   R4 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{x}, If[x y < 0., Print[y x]; Goto[t], \
Print[y x,  , done]]][ R0]]
7   Return
```

(Notice all the call to `MainEvaluate`)

Now compare to this:

```
toy1 = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Block[{y},
   Label["t"];
   y = RandomReal[{-1., 1.}];
   If[x*y < -0., Goto["t"]];
   x*y
   ]]

Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
CompilePrint[toy1]

    1 argument
        1 Boolean register
        7 Real registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        R0 = A1
        R2 = 1.
        R6 = 7.
        R1 = -1.
        R5 = 0.
        Result = R4

1   
2   R3 = RandomReal[ R1, R2]]
3   R4 = R0 * R3
4   B0 = R4 < R5 (tol R6)
5   if[ !B0] goto 8
6   goto 2
7   goto 8
8   R4 = R0 * R3
9   Return
```

which returns a nicely compiled function without problems.

Comment: The `Print` goes to `MainEvaluate` but other functions are compiled. `Compile[{{x, _Real}},
 Block[{y},
  Label["t"];
  y = RandomReal[{-1., 1.}];
  Print[x*y];
  If[x*y < -0., Goto["t"]];
  Print[y*x, " ", "done"];
  x*y]]`

Comment: Does `CompilationTarget -> "C"` works for this example? For me it does not.

Comment: @PlatoManiac looks like someone forgot to specify the C translation for the label opcode!

Comment: @PlatoManiac Doesn't work for me either. Will anybody post a bug report to Wolfram?