# Goto and Compile

Tags: bugs, compile

```
Clear[sum];
sum = Compile[{{n0, _Integer}, {s0, _Integer}},
   Block[{n = n0, s = s0},
    Label["t"];
    If[n > 0, s += n; n--; Goto["t"]];
    s
    ]
   ];

sum[10, 0]
```

It seems that the `Label` is not found. How to make it works?

Comment: The issue appears to relate to compile as the non-compiled function works without problem:

    `sumnc[n0_, s0_] :=
      Block[{n = n0, s = s0},
       Label[t];
       If[n > 0, s += n; n--; Goto[t],
        s]];
    sumnc[10, 0]`


The last line yields 55

I look forward to clarification from the experts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Goto and Label in compiled function?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10491/using-goto-and-label-in-compiled-function)

Comment: I retract my close as duplicate vote as the linked question is strongly related, but the issue is slightly different in this case (see my answer).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like the compiler has troubles when `Goto` appears as a compound statement in `If`. It causes a call to `MainEvaluate` for this part of the code which, as shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10491/using-goto-and-label-in-compiled-function), means calling a labelled `Goto` where the compiler already removed the `Label`.

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]

CompilePrint[sum]

    2 arguments
    1 Boolean register
    9 Integer registers
    Underflow checking off
    Overflow checking off
    Integer overflow checking on
    RuntimeAttributes -> {}

    I0 = A1
    I1 = A2
    I7 = 1
    I5 = 0
    Result = I4

1   I2 = I0
2   I4 = I1
3   
4   B0 = I5 < I2
5   if[ !B0] goto 8
6   V17I2I4 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{n0, s0, nCompile$22, sCompile$23}, 
                Block[{n = nCompile$22, s = sCompile$23}, 
                      {s += n; n--; Goto[t], n, s}]][ I0, I1, I2, I4]]
7   goto 8
8   Return
```

If you rewrite it to move the compound statement out of the `If`:

```
Clear[sum];
sum = Compile[{{n0, _Integer}, {s0, _Integer}},
   Block[{n = n0, s = s0},
    Label["t"];
    If[n <= 0, Goto["end"]];
    s += n; n--; Goto["t"];
    Label["end"];
    s]];

sum[10, 0]
```

> 55

it works as intended.

Comment: I just noted that @LeonidShifrin's deleted answer in the question I referred to seems to say something to the same extent. In short, anything that causes the part of the code that contains `Goto` to generate an `MEvaluate` call will fail. That could be a non-compilable `Print` as in the other question, but also apparently `CompundExpression` with `Goto` as is the case here.

Answer (score 3):

Sjoerd's answer already gives the solution. Let me try to dig a bit deeper. In the *Details* section of the [`Goto`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Goto.html) documentation one finds

> Goto first scans any compound expression in which it appears directly, then scans compound expressions that enclose this one.

This suggests to me that `Goto` only works iff the `Label` is in the same `CompoundExpression` or in an enclosed one. If we look at a simplified version of the OP's code we see

```
Hold[(Label[t];
   If[True,
    Goto[t];
    ];
   s)] // TreeForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

that `CompoundExpression` containing the `Goto` is not *enclosed* by another one. It is enclosed by an `If` expression. Sjoerds solution circumvents this by eliminating the `CompoundExpression` inside the `If` thus leaving outer `CompoundExpression` as first reachable one.

```
Hold[(
   Label["t"];
   If[True, Goto["end"]];
   Goto["t"];
   Label["end"])] // TreeForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Unfortunately, this is not the end of the story. It seems that with `Compile` exactly this "scan for the next enclosed `CompoundExpression`" does not work correctly. Let's take one very simple example

```
Hold[(1; Goto["end"]; 2; Label["end"]; 3)] // TreeForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If one compiles this code, it will work as expected: no `MainEvaluate`. Although, if you nest the `CompoundExpression` by simply using some parenthesis

```
Hold[((1; Goto["end"]); 2; Label["end"]; 3)] // TreeForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The code will not compile. This leaves only one conclusion: Be careful when you work with `Goto` and `Compile`, it might not work as expected.

Comment: Nice. As to your closing sentence: We knew this, of course: https://cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd02xx/EWD215.PDF