# How to use Compile to efficiently apply a function to every element of a list

Tags: compile, pure-function

Let's say I have a list of random numbers;

```
list = Table[Random[], {100000}];
```

I want to apply a function `f` in every element of the list and take their sum. An obvious solution to that would be

```
Total[f[list]]
```

For the sake of clarity I am using here the following simple `f`:

```
f=#^2&;SetAttributes[f, Listable]
```

(Of course, the function `Power` is `Listable` by default

```
Do[Total[f[list]],{100}]//AbsoluteTiming
```

outputs `0.158` on my machine.)

But as always I want the fastest routine I can get. So I used `Compile` to reduce the running time:

```
fc=Compile[{{list,_Real,1}},Total[f[list]]];
```

Testing with

```
Do[fc[list],{100}]//AbsoluteTiming
```

I got a worse result, namely `0.288`! `:-(`

I tested again putting `f` by hand inside the compiled function:

```
fcfast=Compile[{{list,_Real,1}},Total[list^2]];
Do[fcfast[list], {100}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Output was `0.054` and I was pleased!

Why is this happening? How can I speed up my routines without having to put the function explicitly inside `Compile`?

Sjoerd C. de Vries answered on the question [Using Apply inside Compile](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35298/goto-and-compile) tracing with `Needs["CompiledFunctionTools"]` and the function `CompilePrint` that explains the timing differences but I still don't know how to improve that.

**Results after applying the best solution** :

I am adding here my test results using for various implementations. I added `CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}` which answered my question.

The list i used contained 1000000 random numbers , `f=#^2&` and the compiler used was the MinGW.
[image]

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries thank you for the edit. I re-edited to add a relevant question you had answered.

Comment: Well, thanks for referring to my answer. However, I have some difficulties seeing the connection. It's about `Goto` and `Compile` and does not deal with timing.

Comment: When running CompilePrint for the two compiled functions i got differences in one line. fc gave T(R1)1 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[f][ T(R1)0]] and fcfast gave T(R1)1 = Square[ T(R1)0].

Comment: [Related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24595/862)

Comment: it doesn't make a difference to the suggested solution, but I think it should be noted that `f=#^2&;SetAttributes[f, Listable]` does not achieve what you expect, the attributes of `f` don't influence how the pure function is evaluated. You woul instead want `f=Function[Null,#^2,Listable]`. Of course, as you mentioned, here it doesn't make a difference since `Power` is listable anyway. You can see the difference when using any function that isn't listable instead of `Power`...

Comment: FYI for f=#^2& , Compile[{{list, _Real, 1}}, Module[{sum = 0.}, Scan[sum += f[#] &, list]; sum], CompilationTarget -> "C", CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}] was the most efficient routine adding 1 million squared random numbers in only 0.0067 of a second (~150 millions per sec). I used the MinGW compiler. I am adding a picture above with all results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why is this happening? How can I speed up my routines without having to put the function explicitly inside Compile?

It is happening because `Compile` has the attribute `HoldAll`

```
Attributes[Compile]

(* {HoldAll, Protected} *)
```

This means, that no evaluation of the arguments will happen. In your case the arguments to your `Compile` call are `{{list,_Real,1}}` and `Total[f[list]]]`. While you *think* that your definition of `f` is put inside there, exactly this does not happen. It will stay unevaluated as you can see in the output of `CompilePrint`

```
<< CompiledFunctionTools`
CompilePrint[Compile[{{list, _Real, 1}}, Total[f[list]]]]

(*.....
1   T(R1)1 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[f][ T(R1)0]]
2   R0 = TotalAll[ T(R1)1, I0]]
3   Return
" *)
```

Therefore, your compiled function cannot calculate the `Total` directly, it has to ask the Kernel every time the function is called. This results directly in a slowdown. A really easy solution to your problem is to use `With` because it replaces every occurrence of a *named value* with it's value. I didn't write *variable* on purpose here, because in `With` you don't define *variables*, instead it is more like constant defines. Although looking a bit awkward, this

```
fc = With[{f = f},
  Compile[{{list, _Real, 1}}, Total[f[list]]]
]
```

is one solution of your problem. What happens is that the named identifier `f` on the left hand side of the `=` in the `With` call is connected to the *value* of your global `f`. Inside the body of the `With`, every occurrence of `f` is replaced by this value, just like you would copy and paste it manually.

Another way for injection would be

```
fc = Function[func, Compile[{{list, _Real, 1}}, Total[func[list]]]][f]
```

which has the short form

```
fc = Compile[{{list, _Real, 1}}, Total[#[list]]] &[f]
```

Or you can even use `Replace` in combination with `Hold`.

In the end, you should follow Sjoerd's suggestion and use `CompilePrint` to check whether you compiled function works how you expect it.

### Update:

Simon reminded me that there is another simple solution, which is the `"InlineExternalDefinitions"` options:

```
Compile[{{list, _Real, 1}}, Total[f[list]], 
 CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]
```

Comment: thank you very much. At last i can compile my functions the way i want. One note : New timings were much closer to that of Compile[{{list,_Real,1}},Total[list^2]]. In fact they were just x2.I used in both "With" and "&[f]" the CompilePrint and noticed that the only difference with the explicitly defined one was one extra line at the top T(R1)1 = CopyTensor[ T(R1)0]]. I have no problem with this overhead i am just wondering if it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: I think it would be good to mention the option `CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}` as well.

Comment: @SimonWoods Thanks, I forgot about this one.

Comment: Thanks @SimonWoods and Halirutan , the CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True} is the most transparent and efficient of all.