# How to properly (efficiently) define a mixture distribution and optimize the likelihood?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, distributions, performance-tuning

To start with:

```
link3 = {679, 531, 379, 272, 198, 143, 99, 67, 46, 32, 22, 14, 9, 5, 3, 1};
klink3 = 20;
B1997 = {14, 10, 6, 3, 3, 6, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1};
kB1997 = 50;
taxicabsA = {142, 81, 49, 7, 3, 1};
ktaxicabsA = 10;
rabbits = {43, 16, 8, 6, 0, 2, 1};
krabbits = 18;


mylik[data_, kdata_] := Block[
    {K, mypdf, fj, pj, loglik},
    K = kdata;
    mypdf = ProbabilityDistribution[
        Binomial[K, j]*(
        w*p^j*(1 - p)^(K - j) 
        + 
        (1 - w)*Beta[alpha + j, beta + K - j]/Beta[alpha, beta]), {j, 0, K, 1}
    ];

    fj = Prepend[PadRight[data, K], f0];
    pj = PDF[mypdf, #] & /@ Range[0, K];
    loglik = 
    LogGamma[Total[fj] + 1] - Total[LogGamma[fj + 1]] + fj.Log[pj]
];


cons = {f0 > 0, alpha > 0, beta > 0, 0 < p < 1, 0 < w < 1};
pars = {f0, p, w, alpha, beta};
```

We will first take a look at:

```
NMaximize[{mylik[link3, klink3], cons}, pars, Method -> {"RandomSearch", "SearchPoints" -> Automatic}]
NMaximize[{mylik[link3, klink3], cons}, pars, Method -> {"RandomSearch", "SearchPoints" -> 200}]

(* Automatic is better, multiple search points is no good *) 

NMaximize[{mylik[B1997,kB1997], cons}, pars, Method -> {"RandomSearch", "SearchPoints" -> Automatic}]
NMaximize[{mylik[B1997,kB1997], cons}, pars, Method -> {"RandomSearch", "SearchPoints" -> 200}]

(* Automatic is not good enough, multiple search points is useful *)
```

How about some other methods?

Try with `DifferentialEvolution`:

```
OptMethod="DifferentialEvolution";

NMaximize[{mylik[B1997,kB1997], cons}, pars, Method -> {OptMethod, "SearchPoints" -> Automatic}]
NMaximize[{mylik[B1997,kB1997], cons}, pars, Method -> {OptMethod, "SearchPoints" -> 200}]
NMaximize[{mylik[link3, klink3], cons}, pars, Method -> {OptMethod, "SearchPoints" -> Automatic}]
NMaximize[{mylik[link3, klink3], cons}, pars, Method -> {OptMethod, "SearchPoints" -> 200}]

(* None of the above result is optimal *)
```

Try with `SimulatedAnnealing`:

```
OptMethod="SimulatedAnnealing";

NMaximize[{mylik[B1997,kB1997], cons}, pars, Method -> {OptMethod, "SearchPoints" -> Automatic}]
NMaximize[{mylik[B1997,kB1997], cons}, pars, Method -> {OptMethod, "SearchPoints" -> 200}]
NMaximize[{mylik[link3, klink3], cons}, pars, Method -> {OptMethod, "SearchPoints" -> Automatic}]
NMaximize[{mylik[link3, klink3], cons}, pars, Method -> {OptMethod, "SearchPoints" -> 200}]

(* None of the above result is optimal *)
```

So my main questions are:

1. If I want to write a general routine (function) for different datasets, what method do I use? I dont want to use too many search points and see from above, sometimes, it's even worse.
2. What is the proper way to setup a mixture distribution? For this example, it's a mixture of binomial and betabinomial distribution. I have tried to setup the probabilities using many other ways, such as:

   pj = Table[ Binomial[K, j]*(w*p^j*(1 - p)^(K - j) + (1 - w)* Beta[alpha + j, beta + K - j]/Beta[alpha, beta]), {j, 0, K}]

   (* OR *)

   pj = MixtureDistribution[{w,1-w},{BinomialDistribution[K,p],BetaBinomialDistribution[alpha,beta,K]}];
   pj = Table[PDF[pj,j],{j,0,K}]

   (* OR *)

   pj = Table[w*PDF[BinomialDistribution[K, p], j] + (1 - w)*PDF[BetaBinomialDistribution[alpha, beta, K], j], {j, 0, K}]

   (* Sorry about the poor format, but i just can't get the code out of the list environment *)
3. I have even tried to compile the likelihood function, but it does not seem to help. In terms of speed or the optimization result. Most cases, if I check `CompilePrint`, there are still a lot of `MainEvaluate`. I think that's why there is no speed up.

All I want, is (hopefully) to speed up the optimization, settle at the global optima using less "SearchPoints" and a general way to adapt to the toy datasets. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

**Update:**

A lot of the tips (tricks) says that `bultin` functions are better, so I tried this:

```
mylik3[data_, kdata_] := Block[
    {K, mypdf, fj, pj, loglik},
    K = kdata;
    mypdf = ProbabilityDistribution[
        w*PDF[BinomialDistribution[K,p],j]
        + 
        (1 - w)*PDF[BetaBinomialDistribution[alpha,beta,K],j], {j, 0, K, 1}
    ];

    fj = Prepend[PadRight[data, K], f0];
    pj = PDF[mypdf, #] & /@ Range[0, K];
    loglik = 
    LogGamma[Total[fj] + 1] - Total[LogGamma[fj + 1]] + fj.Log[pj]
];
```

But this is not better (or faster) at all.

Comment: I don't understand how this question differs from the last one that I already answered as a comment, apart from the part about the mixture distribution? I already told you that `"SearchPoints"` has hardly any useful effect for differential evolution and to modify `"ScalingFactor"` and `"CrossProbability"` instead. `NMaximize[{mylik[B1997, kB1997], cons}, pars,  Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "ScalingFactor" -> 0.90, "CrossProbability" -> 0.05}]` and `NMaximize[{mylik[link3, klink3], cons}, pars, Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "ScalingFactor" -> 0.90, "CrossProbability" -> 0.05}]` ...

Comment: ... work perfectly fine, as expected, although it certainly would help `NMaximize` if your function also did not return nonsense values like `Indeterminate` for certain values of the parameters.

Comment: I do appreciate your help! However, if I try your settings on `taxicabsA`, it returns a likelihood value of `-16.3518`. But I knew there is a better one `-16.3354`, which would give a huge difference on the parameter values. I want to keep search points merely as a way to `ensure` I found the `best` global optima. I spend a lot of time, search on different ways to produce `MixtureDistributions` because I dont know whether they will make a difference in the optimization. If `bultin` functions are `faster`, would that be more `efficient` to use?

Comment: @OleksandrR. For your information, the `taxicabsA` data should have these values `{alpha -> 5714973, beta -> 31443412, w -> 1 - 0.6243, f0 -> 180.3501, p -> 0.0317}`, which gives a target function value of `-16.3354`.

Comment: Changing the number of search points *does not help* for differential evolution. In fact, it can even *make matters worse* to choose an excessive number. There are also no universal values of the tuning parameters that will work for every problem--global optimization is an open question and major field of research, and you just cannot expect to solve it so easily. Normally one either knows something a priori about the problem, or otherwise, another way to approach it is to meta-optimize the tuning parameters, as I did [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27827/#27862).

Comment: Yes, I understand it's a difficult question. That is why I spend a lot time on finding the `proper` way to compute the likelihood function. So that I can use more search points (using randomsearch). I think randomsearch will explore a `wider` parameter space if more points are used, so a better chance to find the global optima?

Comment: @OleksandrR. I know that I lot of people tend to use differential evolution. But I personally think randomsearch is more suitable (with multiple search points) to explorer a wider parameter space?

Comment: Well, I'm not going to say that you're wrong, because this is your decision to make. But, differential evolution doesn't work like it seems that you think it works; not at all. There are entire books about it that you may find useful. Not that DE is necessarily the best method in general, but I would be confident in saying that it's the best method that's been implemented in *Mathematica*, if you get the tuning parameters right (even though the implementation is not perfect). Using random search is rather like using Nelder-Mead as in the linked question. They are both pseudo-local optimizers.

Comment: Does Maple do any better on any of these problems, by the way?

Comment: Quick answer is Maple does not have Global Optimization tools built in. You have to purchase a different add on license for it. Shall we continue to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19625/discussion-between-chen-stats-yu-and-oleksandr-r).