# No Speedup Compiled Function in FindMinimum

Tags: mathematical-optimization, compile

The problem: I would like to minimize an objective function with respect to 12 variables. Minimization should be executed as fast as possible. Compiling the objective function increases the execution speed of the objective function but does not improve minimization speed.

1) Setup

- The Function is written in the following form:

  FUNCTIONSYSTEMPART1 = Function[{time, c1, c2, rho, YY},    Evaluate[WORKINGSYSTEMPART1[[time]]]];
- In order to Speed up the process, I have compiled the objective function

  COMPILEDSYSTEMPART1 = Compile[{{time, _Integer, 0}, {c1, _Real, 0}, {c2, _Real, 0}, {rho,_Real, 0}, {YY, _Real, 1}}, Evaluate[WORKINGSYSTEMPART1[[time]]]];

Note that the arguments time, c1 ,c2 and rho given as numerics. WORKINGSYSTEMPART1[[time]] represents the objective function. The only unknown variables are stored in YY which is a 12x1 Array.

2) Execution of Objective Function is much faster if the objective function is compiled:

```
In[400]:= AbsoluteTiming[
Do[FUNCTIONSYSTEMPART1[time, 1, 1, 0.55, ConstantArray[3, 12]], {j, 1, 100000}]]
Out[400]= {8.2444715, Null}

In[401]:= AbsoluteTiming[
Do[COMPILEDSYSTEMPART1[time, 1, 1, 0.55, ConstantArray[3, 12]], {j, 1, 100000}]]
Out[401]= {0.3740214, Null}
```

3) The Speedup is not preserved when the Minimization Function is called.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
Quiet[FindMinimum[FUNCTIONSYSTEMPART1[time, 1, 1, 0.55, Z], S, WorkingPrecision -> \[CapitalXi]0]]]
{0.3300188, ... }

AbsoluteTiming[
Quiet[FindMinimum[COMPILEDSYSTEMPART1[time, 1, 1, 0.55, Z], S, WorkingPrecision -> \[CapitalXi]0]]]
{0.3310190, ... }
```

Question: How is it possible that the speedup (attained by compiling the objective function) is lost?

Comment: This might also help: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/shaving-the-last-50-ms-off-nminimize

Comment: I don't see how `Evaluate[WORKINGSYSTEMPART1[[time]]]` can work as described.  The variable `time` is not a actual integer at the time of compilation, but an argument of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you use arbitrary precision arithmetics in `FindMinimum`. But you should realize that compiled function can work only with `MachinePrecision` (machine numbers, without arbitrary precision arithmetics). Apart of this, compiled function cannot be handled symbolically. It means that `FindMinimum` must use finite differences to estimate the derivatives instead of computing them symbolically. This will result in many more evaluations of the objective function.

Comment: Thanks! Both the non compiled and the compiled function here are evaluated numerically do that cannot be the issue . Regarding the machine precision argument, it this modifiable by setting MachinePrecision -> x or is this a in built default value that cannot be adjusted?

Comment: @Breugem There is no option called `MachinePrecision`, please read the Documentation page for [`MachinePrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MachinePrecision.html) to understand what it means. AFAIK `Compile` always works with `MachinePrecision` and it cannot be changed. If you specify `WorkingPrecision` for `FindMinimum` other than `MachinePrecision` you will still work with `MachinePrecision` if the objective function returns machine numbers.