# NMinimize seems to call function with the same values multiple times

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization, number-representation

I have to minimize a function where the evaluation of one parameter set takes very long (around 5sec) and discovered alongside, that `NMinimize` seems to call this function multiple times with the exact same values. As an example, consider the code

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := (Print[N[x, 10]]; x^2);
NMinimize[{f[x]}, x, Method -> "RandomSearch"]
```

The first couple of lines of the output are:

```
-0.829053
-0.829053
-0.829053
-0.829052
-0.329053
-0.329053
-0.329052
-8.85837*10^-9
-8.85837*10^-9
 6.0428*10^-9
```

Am I missing something? The same output is also produced by setting `PrecisionGoal -> 3` and `AccuracyGoal -> 3`, thus we can rule out that the numbers in the output are just identical representations of different numbers.

Comment: You can do this with `g[x_] = x^2`,  `{sol, data} = 
  Reap[NMinimize[{g[x]}, x, Method -> "RandomSearch", 
    EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, g[x]}]]]; ` and look at `data`.

Comment: I've observed this as well. I haven't investigated it thoroughly (you could use the [diagnostic output](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/4708#4708) if you want to see in detail what's going on) but the problem seems to be that in most cases *Mathematica* doesn't save the objective function value anywhere, so wherever it's required, it just gets reevaluated. `NMinimize` is great because of its very general constraint handling, but it isn't the most efficient choice in most cases. Perhaps try `FindMinimum` or, if you don't need constraints, my own Nelder-Mead optimizer.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why manual memonization does not help. `ClearAll@f;
f[x_?NumericQ] := (f[x] = (Print[N[x, 10]]; x^2));
NMinimize[f[x], x, Method -> "RandomSearch"]`. So I guess f gets converted/compiled under the hood...

Comment: In addition to the useful suggestions from @Oleksandr R., you could define your function so that it memoizes, that is `f[x_?NumericQ]:= f[x]=...`. This will not prevent all reevaluations but I find that it can help. Caveat: you might need to sporadically clear out definitions so as not to use too much memory.

Comment: I find the memoization works: `ClearAll[f, g]; g = {}; 
f[x_?NumericQ] := f[x] = (g = {g, x}; x^2); NMinimize[f[x], x, 
 Method -> "RandomSearch"]; DuplicateFreeQ[Flatten[g]]` returns `True`.

Comment: @ecoxlinux, no it does not, because `ClearAll[f, g]; g = {}; f[x_?NumericQ] := (g = {g, x}; x^2); NMinimize[f[x], x, Method -> "RandomSearch"]; DuplicateFreeQ[Flatten[g]]` returns `False`. In your example, if `f[x]` is requested the second time for the same `x`-value, `g={g,x}` is not executed.

Comment: @FrederikZiebell I don't understand your comment. I stated that the above code seems to always returns True in my computer. Are you saying that it returns False in yours?

Comment: I have doubts about the usefulness of memoization in this context. Most of the memoized values will never be accessed again, so unless you do it in such a way as to save only a few of the most recent results, it represents mostly wasted effort as a workaround for a design issue in `NMinimize`.