# Model fitting to noisy data with a custom minimization function

Tags: fitting, modeling

I'm looking into fitting some data with Mathematica. I've got my head around how `NonlinearModelFit` works (I've been using the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm for some other work).

But my data this time is Poisson distributed, and I want to see if using the appropriate MLE for Poisson data is better for my scenario than nonlinear least squares fitting.

According to the paper [Efficient Levenberg-Marquardt minimization of the maximum likelihood estimator for Poisson deviates](https://e-reports-ext.llnl.gov/pdf/382281.pdf), then the minimization for least-squares fitting, for data $y_{i}$ and the model $f_{i}$ is

$$
\chi^{2}=2\sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{\left ( f_{i}-y_{i} \right )^{2}}{\sigma_{i}^{2}}
$$

whereas for Poisson distributed data according to the paper, the minimization is

$$
\chi^{2}=2\sum_{i=1}^{N}f_{i}-y_{i}-2\sum_{i=1,y\neq 0}^{N}y_{i}\ln \left ( \frac{f_{i}}{y_i} \right )
$$

Is it possible to run a model-fitting in Mathematica using this minimization? And can a (modified?) Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm still be used?

**Edit**

There's an associated Nature Methods letter at http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nmeth0510-338, with a revised version of the above link: http://www.nature.com/nmeth/journal/v7/n5/extref/nmeth0510-338-S1.pdf (courtesy of @belisarius)

**Update #1**

So here's the sort of data/model I'm looking to fit: the sum of two (or more) Gaussians, which may sometimes overlap as shown in the example below.

The amount of Poisson noise is deliberately significant as I'm dealing with very low counts. I've only posted a one-dimensional example here, but the data is in 2D, so there are more variables (x,y,means,heights,sigma...). I'm happy with using `NonlinearModelFit` to solve the problem, but I'm curious about dealing with the Poisson noise "more appropriately".

```
twoGaussianFunction[x_, A1_, sigma1_, mean1_, A2_, sigma2_, mean2_] := 
    A1 Exp[-((x - mean1)^2/(2 sigma1^2))] + 
    A2 Exp[-((x - mean2)^2/(2 sigma2^2))];

cleandata = Table[twoGaussianFunction[i, 10, 10, 30, 10, 10, 60], {i, 0, 100}];

noisydata = RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[0.5 #]] & /@ cleandata;
ListLinePlot[{cleandata, noisydata}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Comment: You can use the `findfit` function setting the `NormFunction` option. You can select the algorithm with the option `Method->"LevenbergMarquardt"`

Comment: Thanks - how would I set the `NormFunction` option to the desired minimization function?

Comment: You can use `FindMinimum` to minimize this directly. The Levenberg-Marquardt method is only applicable to minimands that are explicitly sums of squares, so I would suggest you use the Broyden-Fletcher-Goldfarb-Shanno (BFGS) method instead (`Method -> "QuasiNewton"`).

Comment: If I understood correctly, the `NormFunction` documentation seems to be misleading, because it doesn't correspond directly to the function to be minimized, but actually how the residuals are to be normed. In your case you aren't working with only the residuals, so I don't think this is applicable.

Comment: I'm a little unsure regarding `FindMinimum` - if I wanted to fit e.g. a Gaussian function to noisy data according to the minimization above, how would I go about doing so? (I guess this is difference to `NonlinearModelFit`, where I can specify a Gaussian with free parameters as the model to be fitted).

Comment: Here I'm suggesting that you just write it directly as a minimization problem. In [(4700)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/), [Ajasja](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/745/ajasja) and I did exactly this to perform a least squares fit using a custom minimizer, but you can of course minimize anything you want. By the way, you may also like to see `GeneralizedLinearModelFit`, which can be used for fitting Poisson-distributed data directly.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Yes, you're right: actually the function given by the OP cannot be used as `NormFunction`. However, one can probably use an indirect approach by restating the problem so that the given chi-square becomes the model and then can minimize the sum of the model values.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, Oleksandr and Massimo, I'll give it some thought!

Comment: I've updated the question with some more information about what I'm trying to do.

Comment: A revised version of the paper www.nature.com/nmeth/journal/v7/n5/extref/nmeth0510-338-S1.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question, I went with the suggestion by [Oleksandr R](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/312/oleksandr-r):

> Here I'm suggesting that you just write it directly as a minimization problem. In [4700](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/shaving-the-last-50-ms-off-nminimize), [Ajasja](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/745/ajasja) and I did exactly this to perform a least squares fit using a custom minimizer, but you can of course minimize anything you want. By the way, you may also like to see `GeneralizedLinearModelFit`, which can be used for fitting Poisson-distributed data directly.

I ended up using `NMinimize` for my problem, rather than `FindMinimum`, but writing it as a minimisation problem was the solution. I used my Gaussian model as $f_{i}$ to solve for the data $y_{i}$ this:

$$
\chi^{2}=2\sum_{i=1}^{N}f_{i}-y_{i}-2\sum_{i=1,y\neq 0}^{N}y_{i}\ln \left ( \frac{f_{i}}{y_i} \right )
$$

as intended, with decent results.

First, the data:

```
twoGaussianFunction[x_, A1_, sigma1_, mean1_, A2_, sigma2_, mean2_] :=
   A1 Exp[-((x - mean1)^2/(2 sigma1^2))] + 
   A2 Exp[-((x - mean2)^2/(2 sigma2^2))];

cleandata = 
  Table[twoGaussianFunction[i, 2, 3, 20, 2, 3, 30], {i, 0, 50}];

noisydata = RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[2 #]]/2 & /@ cleandata;

ListLinePlot[{cleandata, noisydata}, PlotRange -> Full, PlotLegends -> {"Original", "Noisy"}]
```

[image]

Then the minimisation function:

```
minimizeFunction[A1guess_, sigma1guess_, mean1guess_, A2guess_, 
   sigma2guess_, mean2guess_] := 
  2 Sum[twoGaussianFunction[i, A1guess, sigma1guess, mean1guess, 
       A2guess, sigma2guess, mean2guess] - noisydata[[i]], {i, 50}] - 
   2 Sum[If[noisydata[[i]] == 0., 0,noisydata[[i]]*
       Log[twoGaussianFunction[i, A1guess, sigma1guess, mean1guess, 
          A2guess, sigma2guess, mean2guess]/noisydata[[i]]]], {i,50}];
```

Followed by `NMinimize`:

```
bestfit = 
  NMinimize[{minimizeFunction[a, b, c, d, e, f], 
    a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && d > 0 && e > 0 && f > 0},
   {{a, 1, 3},
    {b, 2, 4},
    {c, 15, 25},
    {d, 1, 3},
    {e, 2, 4},
    {f, 25, 35}},
   Method -> "NelderMead",
   MaxIterations -> 100
   ];

cleaneddata = 
  Table[twoGaussianFunction[i, a /. Last[bestfit], b /. Last[bestfit],
     c /. Last[bestfit], d /. Last[bestfit], e /. Last[bestfit], 
    f /. Last[bestfit]], {i, 1, 50}];

ListLinePlot[{cleandata, cleaneddata}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Original", "Fitted"}]
```

[image]

There's probably room for improvement in the way I've implemented it - certainly for speed, perhaps using `Parallelize` in the minimisation function? (That was my first thought). I've still got to test it fully against the standard least-squares method though...

Comment: Very good! Have an upvote for your trouble. If you want a faster Nelder-Mead implementation, have a look at the question I linked to in the comment... but, I agree, verifying correctness is surely the most important task, and performance probably isn't critical for this application anyway.

Comment: Indeed, I might turn to the faster implementation you mentioned when I start doing lots of these fits (if it does turn out to be better of course), thanks for your help!