# Problems extending NelderMeadMinimize into 2D

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting, performance-tuning

**Update**

The eventual route I followed was to adapt a version of the NM-simplex written in C and link to it with MathLink. Once I've tested this out fully I'll post it here.

---

I've been playing around with Oleksandr's compiled Nelder-Mead Minimization function presented here: [Shaving the last 50 ms off NMinimize](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/shaving-the-last-50-ms-off-nminimize)

First, I'll create some sample data. This creates a noisy version of a Gaussian function.

```
gf1[x_] := 1/Sqrt[2 Pi 5^2] Exp[-((x - 25)^2/(2 5^2))];
addSomeGaussianNoise[x_, sig_] := Map[# + RandomVariate[
    NormalDistribution[0., sig]] &, x, {1}];

interval = 0.01;
values = Range[0, 50, interval];
cleandata = gf1[#] & /@ values;
data = addSomeGaussianNoise[cleandata, 0.01];
```

[image]

There are a few ways to minimise the model. I ran `NelderMeadMinimize` from the linked question:

```
fitter = Block[{data = #}, NelderMeadMinimize[Block[{x = values}, 
      Norm[data - 1/Sqrt[2 Pi c^2] Exp[-((x - b)^2/(2 c^2))]]],
      {b,c}]] &;
fitter2 = Block[{data = #}, NelderMeadMinimize[Block[{x = values}, 
      EuclideanDistance[data, 1/Sqrt[2 Pi c^2] Exp[-((x - b)^2/(2 c^2))]]],
      {b, c}]] &;
fitter3 = Block[{data = #}, NelderMeadMinimize[
      Sqrt[Sum[
        Abs[data[[x/interval + 1]] - 1/Sqrt[2 Pi c^2] Exp[-((x - b)^2/(2 c^2))]]^2, 
         {x,values}
      ]],
      {b, c}]] &;
fitter4 = With[{inter = interval, x = Range@Length[#]},
     NelderMeadMinimize[
      Sqrt[Total[
        Abs[#[[x]] - 1/Sqrt[2 Pi c^2] Exp[-(((x - 1)*inter - b)^2/(2 c^2))]]^2]], 
      {b,c}]] &;

fits = fitter /@ {data} // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.299809, {{0.712906, {b -> 24.985, c -> 5.0084}}}}*)

fits2 = fitter2 /@ {data} // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.240542, {{0.712906, {b -> 24.985, c -> 5.0084}}}}*)

fits3 = fitter3 /@ {data} // AbsoluteTiming
(*{6.575716, {{0.712906, {b -> 24.985, c -> 5.0084}}}}*)

fits4 = fitter4 /@ {data} // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.291925, {{0.712906, {b -> 24.985, c -> 5.0084}}}}*)
```

They all return the same result, but in varying times. Interestingly `EuclideanDistance` is slightly faster than `Norm`.

Option 3 isn't well-written - Option 4 is better. Both 3 and 4 are the most obvious ones for me to choose to extend to a 2D (multivariate) Gaussian function, as I understand them better.

Meanwhile, the first 2 options using `Norm` and `EuclideanDistance` are good, but don't allow for a different minimization function such as that in a [question I asked recently](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47539/model-fitting-to-noisy-data-with-a-custom-minimization-function). In that scenario I was happy using `NMinimize`, but now I'm looking to apply this alternative Nelder-Mead method to see what performance gains can be had.

**My question is therefore:**

*How can I get any of the options to work with 2D data rather than 1D data? i.e. fitting a Gaussian function in $x$ and $y$.*

---

Option 3/4 can be improved further, such that the fitting only takes 0.04 seconds, namely:

```
With[{
   epsilon = $MachineEpsilon,
   minimizer = NelderMeadMinimize`Dump`CompiledNelderMead[
     Function[{b, c},
      Block[{y = Range@Length[data]},
       Sqrt[Total[
         Abs[data[[y]] - 1/Sqrt[2 Pi c^2] Exp[-(((y - 1)*interval - b)^2/(2 c^2))]]^2]
        ]]],{b, c},"ReturnValues" -> "AugmentedOptimizedParameters"]
   },
  serialFitter = 
    Compile[{{data, _Real, 1},{interval,_Real}}, 
     minimizer[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2 + 1, 2}], epsilon, -1], 
     CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}, 
     RuntimeOptions -> {"Speed", "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}, 
     CompilationTarget -> "C"];
  ];

serialFitter[data,interval] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.046861, {0.711633, 25.0001, 5.02656}} *)
```

---

**Update #1**

This creates the 2D data

```
gf[x_, y_] := 1/Sqrt[2 Pi 5^2] Exp[-((x - 25)^2/(2 5^2) + (y - 25)^2/(2 5^2))];
addSomeGaussianNoise[x_, sig_] := 
       Map[# + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0., sig]] &, x, {2}];
interval = 1.;
cleandata = Table[gf[x, y], {x, 0, 50, interval}, {y, 0, 50, interval}];
data = addSomeGaussianNoise[cleandata, 0.01];
```

I then try and fit with this, where I've flattened the 2D data to a 1D vector prior to fitting.

```
fitter = Compile[{{data, _Real, 1}, {interval, _Real}},
   NelderMeadMinimize`Dump`CompiledNelderMead[
     Function[
      {b, c, d},
      Block[{x = Range@Length[data], n = Sqrt[Length[data]]},
       Sqrt[
        Total[
         Abs[
           data[[x]] - 
            1/Sqrt[2 Pi c^2] Exp[-((Floor[Mod[x - 1, n]]*interval - b)^2/(2 c^2) +  
              (Quotient[x - 1, n]*interval - d)^2/(2 c^2))]]^2]
        ]
       ]
      ],
     {b, c, d}, "ReturnValues" -> "AugmentedOptimizedParameters"]
    [RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3 + 1, 3}], $MachineEpsilon, -1],
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}, 
   RuntimeOptions -> {"Speed", "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False},
   CompilationTarget -> "C"];

fitter[Flatten[data], 1.] // AbsoluteTiming
```

However, I get errors:

> CompiledFunction::cfte: Compiled expression {0.874982,0.207452,-0.119287,0.635137} should be a rank 2 tensor of machine-size real numbers.
>
> CompiledFunction::cfexe: Could not complete external evaluation; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.

It's nearly there as a solution to my problem, but not quite!

**Update #2**

The first error (`cfte`) refers to the `"ReturnValues"` option - if I change it from `"AugmentedOptimizedParameters"` to `"OptimizedParameters"` the error now says

> CompiledFunction::cfte: "Compiled expression {-0.053765,0.291736,0.432465} should be a rank 2 tensor of machine-size real numbers.

See how it's changed length? The function is expecting the return values to be a rank 2 tensor, but they're not...

Comment: Perhaps Oleksandr is the best-placed person to answer this (it's his code after all), but any help appreciated!

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by two-dimensional? The sum of two of these Gaussian curves as in the linked question?--or is it that rather than a univariate Gaussian, you want to find the best fitting multivariate Gaussian? NM minimizes a function $f(\vec{v}) : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^1$ with respect to $\vec{v}$, so as long as you can cast your problem in this form, you can do it.

Comment: Sorry, yes, by 2D I mean a Gaussian with an `x` and `y` component (so multivariate) - the problem I'm having is getting my answer below to work with data in the form of a 2D rather than 1D list.

Comment: Also, `NelderMeadMinimize` compiles whatever is passed to it, so this should be a self-contained problem (without any references to external symbols) if calls out of the VM are to be avoided. Otherwise you have to use `NelderMeadMinimize\`Dump\`CompiledNelderMead` to produce the code for the minimizer and write the surrounding code yourself so that all of the necessary symbols are defined within the VM on entry. Failure to do so will still produce a result, but the many calls out of the VM present a performance problem.

Comment: Indeed, I realised this earlier today and rewrote my final method (#3) to work much faster, which it now does, but I'm struggling to get it to work with passing 2D data instead of 1D data as I've done here.

Comment: Your question seems like it should be reasonably straightforward to address, but I have things I need to do until later this evening. Can I get back to you in a few hours?

Comment: Absolutely, there's no rush - thank you!

Comment: Sorry about the delay in replying--I had been playing around with your chi-square goodness of fit statistic from the other post and found it a bit difficult to work with. But that's not a fundamental limitation and I'll write an answer later. Basically the problem can be reduced to changing your residual matrix into a residual vector and treating it as usual; the mathematics is the same either way, so you can just `Flatten` it if you want...

Comment: That's ok - I had a similar thought last night but I'm away from a computer with Mathematica until tomorrow - I look forward to your answer!

Comment: Just so you know, I have written some code for you which is almost working, but I'm having some trouble with type inference (a perennial problem with the *Mathematica* compiler). As soon as I've debugged it, I'll post the result.

Comment: Would one of you be willing to post an updated example of the compiled NelderMead code fitting a multivariate Gaussian? I am still confused by the discussion in the comments. Thanks!

Comment: @OleksandrR. is it possible to monitor the outcome as it proceeds with this package? something like  EvaluationMonitor :> ?