# How to make a twice-differentiable function that approximates some data?

Tags: function-construction, fitting, approximation

I have some time series data that I would like to approximate with a twice-differentiable function.  Each time series has ~10,000 datapoints, so I definitely do *not* want a function that passes through all these points.  This rules out using `InterpolatingFunction`.

I have no mathematical model for these data at all, otherwise I would use `LinearModelFit` or `NonlinearModelFit` for this.

The only solution I can think of would be to perform some type of smoothing on the data (`LowpassFilter`?), and then somehow generate an approximating function object from the smoothed data.

Is there a built-in function for doing this sort of thing?  (It's not that I think there's anything wrong with the recipe outlined above, but as a rule I prefer to use built-in methods over home-spun ones whenever possible.)

Comment: What about splines? They should work pretty well.

Comment: did you mean to say you "do *not* want to pass though" all the points?

Comment: @george2079: thanks!  I just edited the post to add the missing "not".

Comment: This recent question seems related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85212/derivative-of-contour-in-contourplot

Comment: Here is a method I have used that smoothes and uses interpolation at the same time:http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72037/12558

Comment: If your datapoints are equally-spaced [you can use the Savitzky-Golay filter](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37380/savitzky-golay-filter-to-smooth-noisy-data#comment113105_37413).