# Finding a best fit without having to specify the form of the equation

Tags: fitting

Well the title actually says it all. Is there a function that finds the best fit for data points without any user-inputed information about the form the formula might have?

Here is the data I want to find a fit for: `data={8, 11.2, 10.3, 8.1, 13.6, 2.8, 3.2, 1.3, 1.8, 1, 0.3, 0.2, 0, 2.1}` It is the annual sales of DVD-A from 2001 to 2014 (this is the whole dataset). In 2003, a direct competitor to the DVD-A appeared, the SA-CD. So I would like to graphically illustrate the fact that the trend in the sales of the DVD-A change drastically from the moment the SA-CD made it's appearance. Obviously, there are only two observations before 2003, so a linear fit is obvious... But I'm having trouble finding a continuous function that illustrates the sales trend from 2003 to 2014.

So the predictor variable is simply `{3,4,...,14}`.

Here is a graph of the data, the linear trend for the years 2001 and 2002 and the chopped-up function for the 2003-2014 period provided by the `FindFormula` described below:

[image]

Code for the graph:

`Show[ListLinePlot[data,(*DVD-A*)
      PlotStyle ->Directive[CMYKColor[0.37,0.,0.44,0.48]
        ,Thickness[.008],Opacity[.5]]
        ,Frame -> True
        ,PlotRange -> All
        ,FrameTicks-> {Automatic, {Table[{i, 2000 + i}, {i, 0, 14}], None}}
        ,PlotLabel -> "Sales evolution of DVD-A"
        ,FrameLabel -> {None, "Sales\n(Millions, 2013 USD)"}]
    ,Plot[Evaluate@LinearModelFit[data[[{1,2}]], t, t][t], {t, 0.75, 2.5}]
    ,Plot[Evaluate@FindFormula[data[[3;;]], t, 5,SpecificityGoal -> 3][[4]], {t,4, 14}] ]`

Until now, I have tried this: `FindFormula[data[[3;;]], t, 5, SpecificityGoal -> 3]`, which gives a chopped-up fonction with different chunks. I would like to find a continuous function that fits the data (I already tried with `NonlinearFit` with different orders polynomials and did not get a visually good estimation of the data from 2003 to 2014).

Thanks,

Comment: You might try `FindFormula` if you have version 10.2 or above.  But you still need to examine the fit afterwords.

Comment: If all the output I get is a real number, I guess this means that the software can't find a better fit than a straight line?

Comment: I posted a method here that should work. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72037/12558 can you give us some data?

Comment: It might just be that there is no relationship which would explain why the result is just the mean of the dependent variable as the predictor.  It's hard to say more than that unless you share a specific example (data AND code).

Comment: I don't think there is any answer to this question, and there certainly is no answer with out seeing the data.

Comment: I've voted to re-open the question now that you've provided data and a minimal amount of code.  (Although I'm forced to assume that your predictor variables are 1, 2, 3,..., 14.  You should be more explicit.)  If you want more support for re-opening your question, you should include a plot of your data.  Also, if there is some theoretical curve or consistent previous results, you might want to mention that also.  How your data was collected would be important, too, but such things might be better asked at CrossValidated.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I added details to the problem and a graph.

Comment: Well, you're going to think I'm schizophrenic.  Now that you've given more information I don't see that your underlying question is about finding a smooth curve to fit the data.  It's about comparing two different time periods.  So if your question re-opens, I'd vote to close it and suggest that you first ask the question on CrossValidated.  Then you could implement the solution using *Mathematica*.

Comment: You misunderstand the question, I already know hot to compare the different time periods, I'm using a differences-in-differences estimation and using the CD sales as a control group and the arrival of the SA-CD as the shock. The question I'm asking here is indeed about finding a smooth curve to fit the data from 2003 and on. I don't think you're in the advanced stages of the disease yet ;)

Comment: Given the shape of the data, wouldn't it make more sense to suppose that the effect of the new technology was delayed by a few years (rather than crediting both the spike in 2005 and the rapid decline to the same effect)?

Comment: I just changed the negative value to zero. I asked the source of the data of how that could be and this was his answer: "For physical goods, we collect data on “shipments” from music companies to retail stores. Sometimes there are returns of product (from the store to the label), especially smaller formats.  When the returns exceed the shipments over a period you get a net negative number.  It only happens occasionally and with very small formats."

Comment: @bill You are right, but the spike is absolutely insignificant (13 millions is sales) compared to the overall industry (15 billions on 2005). So the spike can also be seen as an ephemeral fluctuation; if it's a problem for finding the right curve, one could just omit that particular year. Thanks for your insight, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Quantile regression](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2014/01/01/quantile-regression-with-b-splines/) might produce results you would want.

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/QuantileRegression.m"]

data = {8, 11.2, 10.3, 8.1, 13.6, 2.8, 3.2, 1.3, 1.8, 1, 0.3, 0.2, 0, 2.1};
ts = Transpose[{Range[2001, 2014], data}];

qfunc = QuantileRegression[ts, 4, {0.5}][[1]];

ListLinePlot[{ts, {#, qfunc[#]} & /@ ts[[All, 1]]}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"data", "QR fit"}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

```
qfunc[x] // Simplify
```

[image]

Comment: Would you add in confidence bands for the curve to help assess the "confidence" in the fit?  I suspect those bands will be so wide as to make the predictions useless.  There just isn't enough data here to put nonparametric quantile regression to work.

Comment: Thank you, this is precisely what I wanted but wasn't able to obtain. For this particular usage I don't need the confidence bands.

Comment: @EBassal You might not want confidence bands but you do *need* them.  Any estimate without some measure of precision is at best of unknown value.  Here with just 14 data points and probably 8 parameters estimated is a case of way overfitting.  This is not an indictment of quantile regression or the great package that Anton has put together.  It is simply a case of overfitting confounded by the ignoring of the cost of not knowing what model might be appropriate.

Comment: @JimBaldwin My answer is for question's request "[...] I'm having trouble finding a continuous function that illustrates the sales trend from 2003 to 2014." In this case using QR I am not starting with a model or trying to find one. Also, theoretically speaking QR is much more ad hoc -- to verify that QR worked I just have to count the points above and below the found curve. (In this case of 14 points for the 0.5 quantile QR worked perfectly: with `Tally[(qfunc[#[[1]]] > #[[2]]) & /@ ts]` we get `{{False, 7}, {True, 7}}`.)

Comment: Anton:  I understand.  This site is about the use of *Mathematica* software and not a statistics, physics, chemistry, astronomy, or engineering site.  However, if someone had a model and data and grammatically correct *Mathematica* code and they predicted that the mass of an electron was twice as big as currently accepted, I would hope that folks would jump all over that prediction.  I'm simply attempting to do the same for statistics when I see the need.  Here quantile regression provides a predicted curve but with huge confidence bands rendering the prediction useless.

Comment: @JimBaldwin The way I see it, OP's question is more about curve fitting than prediction, although the question has been formulated in a prediction set-up. I do not see the point of pushing into the answers the prediction view too much.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that inferences are to be made after passing on the "curve fit" to some statistical test.  So how good the fit is would seem very relevant.  The best fit, of course, it just to use the 14 data points.  That's not very many more parameters than are needed for quantile regression.  And interpolation between years is certainly not needed because only annual sales makes any sense.  Sometimes it's just best to let the data speak for themselves.  (And to repeat: I think your quantile regression package is great.)

Answer (score 4):

I think that @m_goldberg had the right answer in his comment:  "I don't think there is any answer to this question..."

Why do I say this?  Mainly because of the subjective tone you've used.  In other words, when a good curve appears, you'll know it when you see it.  That is not to say that such an approach is wrong.  It's only to say that maybe the rest of us can't help you because of that.

In addition, there are some statements for which there is not much statistical validity:

(1) "Obviously, there are only two observations before 2003, so a linear fit is obvious..."  No, it not obvious but it is inappropriate.

(2) Both DVD-A and SA-CD have had low sales, have never caught on (few musicians recording in such formats), and finding a smooth curve to fit 12 data points won't help you with assigning cause-and-effect.  You mention difference-in-difference techniques which are popular among certain disciplines but the restrictive assumptions are rarely checked and maybe rarely met.

(3) You've given a good rationale for why the sales are negative in one year (because of returns) but no rationale for why converting that to a zero would be appropriate as other years have returns also.

(4) `FindFormula` does not give "a chopped-up fonction with different chunks".  It gives you the top 5 models that you requested.

I'd still recommend first addressing the question at [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) and then using *Mathematica* for implementation.

**Update:  Why you need confidence bands**

At some point adding in more parameters loses effectiveness in fitting and soon one starts to overfit giving you false confidence in the result.  Two ways of assessing the models being considered is to use confidence bands and ranking models by their AICc statistic.  (Overfitting especially applies to good but data hungry techniques such as quantile regression and generalized additive models when one doesn't have many data points to estimate the multiple and "hidden" parameters.)

Here is a summary of fits if you restrict yourself to polynomials of order up to 6 for predicting the values for the years 2003 through 2014.

```
data = {8, 11.2, 10.3, 8.1, 13.6, 2.8, 3.2, 1.3, 1.8, 1, 0.3, 0.2, 0, 2.1};
ts = Transpose[{Range[2001, 2014], data}];
ts2 = Transpose[{Range[3, 14], data[[Range[3, 14]]]}];

fit[order_] := Module[{x, z, i, lm},
  lm = LinearModelFit[ts2, Table[x^i, {i, order}], x];
  Show[Plot[{lm[z - 2000], lm["MeanPredictionBands"] /. x -> z - 2000}, {z, 2003, 2014}],
   ListPlot[ts], AxesOrigin -> {2000, 0}, 
   PlotRange -> {{2001, 2014}, {-5, 20}}, ImageSize -> Medium,
   Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"Sales", ""}, {"Year", 
      "Polynomial order = " <> ToString[order]}}]
  ]

Grid[{{fit[1], fit[2]}, {fit[3], fit[4]}, {fit[5], fit[6]}}]
```

[image: Polynomial fits]

One can see that as the order of the polynomial increases, there is closer agreement to the observed data.  However, a price is paid in that the confidence bands start to get wider and wider.

If one computes the AICc statistic, the 2nd order polynomial has the smallest AICc statistic with the linear model (1st order polynomial) coming in second.  So if you restrict yourself to these polynomials the 2nd order polynomial is best.  Whether or not the confidence bands are small enough to meet your objective is a subject matter issue.  But ignoring the confidence bands is not justifiable.