# Cubic spline Interpolation

Tags: interpolation, data

I'd like to fit a cubic spline object to some data in mathematica. I think I'm ok in how to set it up, I just need a little help with some of the syntax. I'd like to generate a list of data first comprising about 100,000 points. The way I was doing this was to use a `For` loop:

```
For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++, data = {{i,  4*Pi/9/Log[i/0.09]}}]
```

> ```
> {{10, 0.296413}}
> ```

But this only generated the element of data I wanted for `i = 10` (for i up to 100000 the run time seems long, but to express my problem the number of points shouldn't matter). Could someone tell me how to fix the `For` loop so I can obtain 'data' as a brace containing the 10 sets of data points?

I'm also interested in creating a data set with points of the form  e.g {{1.1, f(1.1)}, {1.2, f(1.2)}, {1.3, f(1.3)}, ... }, i.e., where the increment of my x values is 0.1 and not 1 as in the `For` Loop. Is there a way to modify the `For` Loop in this case too?

In the end I expect to evaluate something like

```
cubicsp1 = Interpolation[data]
```

Comment: do not use `For` ( ever ). Look up `Table`  .. `data=Table[{i,  4*Pi/9/Log[i/0.09]},{i,10}]`

Comment: I did something along these lines [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72037/12558) let me know if you need more.

Comment: Note that `Interpolation` by default doesn't construct a smooth natural cubic spline if that's what you are going for, but some kind of piecewise (hermite?) spline (meaning that the first derivative is in general not continuous).

Comment: @CAF The title doesn't reflect the essence of the question. Please make more adequate title.

Answer (score 3):

It wasn't quite clear if you wanted 100,000 points between 1 and 10 or 100,000 points from one to 100,000.

I will assume the former (changing it to the latter is trivial).

I like to use `Table` rather than `Map` because the syntax is easier to follow and the performance almost as good in most cases.

The iterator `{i, 1, 10, 1/10000}` creates 100,000 points between 1 and 10.

```
data = Table[{i, (4 π)/(9 Log[(10 i)/9])}, {i, 1, 10, 1/10000}];
```

Create the interpolation function

```
f = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 3];
```

Compare the data and function

```
Show[
 ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Black],
 Plot[f[x],  {x, 1, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

On this scale they match perfectly.

### Part 2 - NIntegrate

I don't know how many times you are doing this but I found `NIntegrate` to be reasonable with the interpolating function.

```
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 1, 10}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.546858, 10.3072} *)
```

It took about 0.5 seconds on my system (Mathematica 11.1.1, Windows 7, 64 bit, 3.5GHz, 16.0 GB RAM).

In order to speed it up you might reduce the granularity of the data input to the interpolating function. Also, since it becomes very smooth and flat beyond 3 or 4 seconds, make a further reduction of the density in that region.

For for example, below the density is reduced by a factor of two from 1 to 3, and by a factor of 10, from 3 to 10.

```
dataReduced = Join[
   Table[{i, (4 π)/(9 Log[(10 i)/9])}, {i, 1, 3, 2/10000}],
   Table[{i, (4 π)/(9 Log[(10 i)/9])}, {i, 3 + 1/1000, 10, 1/1000}]
   ];

 fR = Interpolation[dataReduces, InterpolationOrder -> 3];

NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 1, 10}] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.53, 10.3072} *)

NIntegrate[fR[x], {x, 1, 10}] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.12, 10.3072} *)
```

This results in a speedup of about a factor of 4 - 5.

Another approach would be to make an `Interpolation` of the integral.

Your input function has a closed form for the integral.

```
Integrate[4 π/(9 Log[(10 x)/9]), x]
(* 2/5 π LogIntegral[(10 x)/9] *)
```

Use that to make a `Table` and an `Interpolation`.

```
dataIntegral = Table[{i, 2/5 π LogIntegral[(10 i)/9]}, {i, 1, 10, 1/10000}];

fI = Interpolation[dataIntegral];
```

and then

```
fI[10] - fI[1] // RepeatedTiming // N
(* {0.0000709202, 10.3072} *)
```

This is blindingly fast.

The answer is particular to your input function which was a closed form for the integration.

What if your input function does not have a closed form? Say it is an arbitrary function `fInput`.

Then you could pay the price once as follows:

```
dataIntegral = Table[{i, NIntegrate[fInput[x], {x, 1, i}]}, {i, 1, 10, 1/10000}];

fI = Interpolation[dataIntegral]
```

That might take a long time to create but once done you will have a rapid response when you invoke `fI`.

Comment: Thanks! I should say I'm also interested in using the interpolating function I get from this analysis as an integrand involved in a numeric integral. Calling `NIntegrate[cubicsp1[j],{j,1,100000}]` seems to be taking a long time. Could you perhaps edit your answer (if you know a way) to modify this line or the way I've set up the interpolating method so that the numerical integration is done quicker?

Comment: I'm new to this way of doing things but I can guess it's something to do with the integral looping over the table of values at every value it needs which might explain the longevity of the running time.

Comment: No problem! I have done so, it is here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/160622/ways-to-quicken-numeric-integral-over-interpolating-spline if you are able to help out. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are much easier ways to construct the data than a For loop. george2079 shows one in the comments, here is another that uses Map (represented by /@) and Slot (represented by #), which essentially fills all the slots in the specified Range. Then f is defined to be an interpolating function (order 3 specifies cubic), and you can evaluate the function f at any point in the range.

```
dat = {#, 4*Pi/9/Log[#/0.09]} & /@ Range[1, 10, 0.1];
f = Interpolation[dat, InterpolationOrder -> 3];
{f[2.2], f[2.211], f[5.03]}
```

Comment: Thanks! I should say I'm also interested in using the interpolating function I get from this analysis as an integrand involved in a numeric integral. Calling `NIntegrate[cubicsp1[j],{j,1,100000}]` seems to be taking a long time. Could you perhaps edit your answer (if you know a way) to modify this line or the way I've set up the interpolating method so that the numerical integration is done quicker?

Comment: You started out with data, then created an interpolating function, now you want to integrate? Why not just *sum* the data in the first place? The interpolating function does not provide any new accuracy over what is in the data itself.

Comment: Ah sorry in order to express the problem I was having with the interpolation, I seemed to have oversimplified what I'm trying to do - basically I have an integral of the form $\int_1^{15000} f_1(k) f_2(k) dk$ where $f_1(k)$ is the interpolating function and $f_2(k)$ is some multiplicative function of k. I'm working with the following `data = Table[{i, AsRunDec[asMz /. NumDef, Mz /. NumDef, i, 2]}, {i, 1,
     15000, 14999/100000}];` and then `f1 = Interpolation[data];`, where RunDec is a specialised mathematica package - I didn't mention this in OP because of its rarity onsite

Comment: Maybe the problem lies with your (unspecified) f2. If I run: `dat = {#, 4*Pi/9/Log[#/0.09]} & /@ Range[1, 100000, 0.1];
f = Interpolation[dat, InterpolationOrder -> 3];
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 1, 100000}] // Timing` it returns in 1.3 seconds.