# Ways to quicken numeric integral over interpolating spline?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, interpolation, splines

I have an integral of the form $$\int_1^{15000} f_1(k) f_2(k) dk,$$ where $f_1(k)$ is an interpolating function and $f_2(k)$ is some multiplicative function of k. I'm working with the following

```
   data = Table[{i, AsRunDec[asMz /. NumDef, Mz /. NumDef, i, 2]}, {i,1, 15000, 14999/100000}];

   f1 = Interpolation[data];
```

Because of the large integration domain, a naive use of `NIntegrate` seems to give rise to a long run time.

```
   NIntegrate[f1[k]*f2[k],{k,1,15000}];
```

I think the longevity is due to mathematica looping over the table of values in `data` over and over again as it performs the integration.
I just wondered what amendments I can make to quicken this evaluation? General methods involving the $f_i$'s and what I've defined above are ok or, if preferred I can post my whole code.

I should say RunDec is a specialised package. Basically for each value of $i$ it returns some value.

Thanks!

Edit: Here is the code I'm working with. Basically I'd like to amend it to make the `NIntegrate` over the interpolating function (here called `cubic1`) quicker. In the notation above, $f_2(k)$ depends on some unknown parameters `NN,a,b` which are determined through a minimisation but probably those details are irrelevant below - I just include for completeness.

```
   Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]

   MasData5 = {{{44.8, 47.5}, ErrorBar[4.0]}, {{54.8, 50.1}, 
ErrorBar[4.2]}, {{64.8, 61.7}, ErrorBar[5.1]}, {{74.8, 64.8}, 
ErrorBar[5.5]}, {{84.9, 75}, ErrorBar[6.2]}, {{94.9, 81.2}, 
ErrorBar[6.7]}, {{104.9, 85.3}, ErrorBar[7.1]}, {{119.5, 94.5}, 
ErrorBar[7.5]}, {{144.1, 101.5}, ErrorBar[8.3]}, {{144.9, 101.9}, 
ErrorBar[10.9]}, {{162.5, 117.8}, 
ErrorBar[12.8]}, {{177.3, 130.2}, 
ErrorBar[13.4]}, {{194.8, 147.7}, 
ErrorBar[17.1]}, {{219.6, 137.4}, 
ErrorBar[20.1]}, {{244.8, 176.6}, 
ErrorBar[20.3]}, {{267.2, 178.7}, 
ErrorBar[21.1]}, {{292.3, 200.4}, ErrorBar[29.1]}, {{60, 55.8}, 
ErrorBar[4.838]}, {{80, 66.6}, ErrorBar[7.280]}, {{100, 73.4}, 
ErrorBar[6.426]}, {{120, 86.7}, ErrorBar[7.245]}, {{140, 104}, 
ErrorBar[12.083]}, {{160, 110}, ErrorBar[16.279]}, {{42.5, 43.8}, 
ErrorBar[3.482]}, {{55, 57.2}, ErrorBar[3.980]}, {{65, 62.5}, 
ErrorBar[4.614]}, {{75, 68.9}, ErrorBar[5.197]}, {{85, 72.1}, 
ErrorBar[5.523]}, {{100, 81.9}, ErrorBar[5.368]}, {{117.5, 95.7}, 
ErrorBar[6.277]}, {{132.5, 103.9}, ErrorBar[6.912]}, {{155, 115}, 
ErrorBar[7.920]}, {{185, 129.1}, ErrorBar[9.192]}, {{215, 141.7}, 
ErrorBar[10.666]}, {{245, 140.3}, ErrorBar[14.526]}, {{275, 189}, 
ErrorBar[24.274]}, {{49, 39.2}, ErrorBar[10]}, {{86, 75.7}, 
ErrorBar[14.414]}, {{167, 118}, ErrorBar[22.828]}, {{43.2, 50.7}, 
ErrorBar[1.5]}, {{50, 59.5}, ErrorBar[1.4]}, {{57.3, 61.8}, 
ErrorBar[1.9]}, {{65.3, 67.6}, ErrorBar[1.7]}, {{73.9, 72.4}, 
ErrorBar[1.9]}, {{83.2, 79.9}, ErrorBar[2.3]}, {{93.3, 84.4}, 
ErrorBar[2.1]}, {{104.3, 86.7}, ErrorBar[2.7]}, {{47.9, 55.4}, 
ErrorBar[2.1]}, {{68.4, 66.4}, ErrorBar[2.9]}};
(*h1 2006 Q^2=0 data,zeus 2002,zeus 2004 and h1 2013 data for Q^2=0*)

gamma = 5.55*^-6;
MJpsi = 3.1;
alphaem = 1/137;
lambda = 0.09;
Ca = 3; (*list of constants *)

xg = NN*((4*qbar)/((4*qbar - MJpsi^2) + w^2))^(-a)*(qbar)^b*Exp[Sqrt[
 16*Ca/9*Log[(4*qbar - MJpsi^2 + w^2)/(4*qbar)]*
  Log[Log[qbar/lambda]/Log[qo/lambda]]]];

data = Table[{i, AsRunDec[asMz /. NumDef, Mz /. NumDef, i, 2]}, {i, 1,
 15000, 14999/100000}];

cubic1 = Interpolation[data];

F5[w_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, NN_?NumericQ] :=Module[{qbarr = 2.4025, qoo = 2, qbar, qo}, (3.89379*^5*1/(4.9 + 4*0.06*Log[w/90])/16*4*Pi^3*MJpsi^3*
  gamma/12/
   alphaem*(NIntegrate[
      cubic1[k]/qbar/(qbar + k)*
         D[(2^(2*(D[Log[xg], 
                Log[1/(((4*qbar))/((4*qbar - MJpsi^2) + w^2))]]
                + 3))/Sqrt[Pi]*
             Gamma[D[Log[xg], 
                Log[1/(((4*qbar))/((4*qbar - MJpsi^2) + w^2))]]
                + 5/2]/
              Gamma[D[Log[xg], 
                Log[1/(((4*qbar))/((4*qbar - MJpsi^2) + w^2))]]
                + 4])*
           NN*(((4*qbar))/((4*qbar - MJpsi^2) + w^2))^(-a)*(k)^b*
           Exp[Sqrt[
             16*Ca/9*Log[(4*qbar - MJpsi^2 + w^2)/(4*qbar)]*
              Log[Log[k/lambda]/Log[qo/lambda]]]], k] /. 
        qbar -> qbarr /. qo -> qoo, {k, 
       qoo, (w^2 - MJpsi^2)/4}] + 
     0.118/qbar/qo*Log[(qbar + qo)/qbar]*
      NN*((4*qbar)/((4*qbar - MJpsi^2) + w^2))^(-a)*(qo)^
       b*(2^(2*(D[Log[xg], 
               Log[1/(((4*qbar))/((4*qbar - MJpsi^2) + w^2))]]
              + 3))/Sqrt[Pi]*
        Gamma[D[Log[xg], 
            Log[1/(((4*qbar))/((4*qbar - MJpsi^2) + w^2))]]
           + 5/2]/
         Gamma[D[Log[xg], 
            Log[1/(((4*qbar))/((4*qbar - MJpsi^2) + w^2))]]
           + 4]))^2) /. qbar -> qbarr /. qo -> qoo]

    chisq5[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, NN_?NumericQ] := Sum[((MasData5[[k, 1, 2]] - F5[MasData5[[k, 1, 1]], a, b, NN])/
  MasData5[[k, 2, 1]])^2, {k, 1, Length[MasData5]}];

  NMinimize[chisq5[a, b, NN], {a, b, NN}];
```

Comment: You are getting some good answers but it would be best to supply the full details because as indicated (see Michael E2 answer) the answers are specific to the problem and don't apply in general.

Comment: @Jack LaVigne Sure, I just uploaded my whole code I'm working with in the OP. I took the lower boundary to be 2 in this case but it doesn't really matter for my purpose, 1 is also ok. Thanks :)

Comment: I copied the code starting with `Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"] and it doesn't run. To make your questions easy for members to answer, a good technique for quality control is to close Mathematica. Then start Mathematia and and in the new notebook copy and run your code copies from the question you have written. If it fails, find the mistake or omission and fix it. At a minimum the definitions for `AsRunDec` and `NumDef` appear to be missing.

Comment: @Jack LaVigne ah yes, sorry RunDec is a specialised Mathematica package and a RunDec.m file needs to be downloaded from the net. Then NumDef will also be understood.

Comment: The link to `RunDef` is ... ?

Comment: @JackLaVigne It is RunDec and here: https://www.ttp.kit.edu/Progdata/ttp00/ttp00-05/ Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

My experience teaches me that most problems tend to be specific, not general.  Here's a way that works for a similar looking problem:

```
f1 = Interpolation@Table[{x, Sin[10 Sin[10 x]]}, {x, 0., 1., 2.^-21}];

NIntegrate[f1[k]*Exp[k], {k, 0, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {2.77656, 0.0636131}  *)
```

100 times faster by hand:

```
npts = 11;
err = 1;
int = 1;
PrintTemporary@Dynamic@{npts, err, int};
(While[
   Abs[err/int] > 10^-10,
   npts = 2 npts + 1;
   {int, err} = Block[{abscissae, weights, errweights},
     {abscissae, weights, errweights} = 
      NIntegrate`GaussKronrodRuleData[npts, MachinePrecision];
     {weights, errweights}.(f1[k]*Exp[k] /. k -> abscissae)
     ]
   ];
  int) // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.023723, 0.0636131}  *)
```

It works because the singularities are negligible and the oscillation moderate.

Comment: I think I am able to follow your hand procedure. I think it would be helpful if you could write a short paragraph explaining the strategy of your code. In particular, I am unfamiliar with NIntegrate`GaussKronrodRuleData` although I can guess what it doesn. When I use 100,000 points rather than 2,000,000 I do not experience an increase in speed.

Comment: @JackLaVigne I'm not sure it's worth working on until the OP responds...Your example is not the OPs nor is mine. See [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#381359375) and [this one](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#16672882) for the use of the rule data.

Comment: Thank you for the references. Very helpful!

Answer (score 4):

I like turning these types of integrals into an ODE. Using @MichaelE2's example:

```
NDSolveValue[
    {int'[k] == f1[k] Exp[k], int[0]==0},
    int[1],
    {k, 0, 1}
] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.139189, 0.0636131}

Answer (score 1):

You can build a simple Riemann sum, if there are a lot of data points and the curve is smooth enough. This is also very fast.

```
tab = Table[{x, Sin[10 Sin[10 x]]}, {x, 0., 1., 2.^-21}];

f1 = Interpolation@tab;
```

Using `FullForm[f1]`, you see, that you can extract the original data points from the `InterpolatingFunction`. (If you don`t know the original data)

```
xval = First@f1[[3]]; yval = f1[[4, 3]];
```

Calculate half of the difference of two neighboring x-values.

```
rot = (Drop[RotateLeft[xval], -1] - Rest@RotateRight[xval])/2;
```

Calculate the multiplicative function

```
expxval = Exp[xval];
```

Build the Riemann sum

```
Total[{Total[rot*Drop[yval, -1]*Drop[expxval, -1]], 
   Total[rot*Rest[yval]*Rest[expxval]]}] // AbsoluteTiming

(*     {0.0780848, 0.0636131}    *)
```

This works for equal and for varying x-distances.