# Integrating an interpolating function: Hermite vs. BSpline

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, interpolation, splines

I have an interpolation through a list of points, which I need to integrate. The minimal working example looks as follows:

```
sin[t_] = Interpolation[Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, \[Pi], \[Pi]/10}], Method -> "Hermite"][t];
Integrate[sin[x], x]

ClearSystemCache[]
Table[Integrate[sin[x], {x, 0, t}] // N, {t, 0, \[Pi], .01}]; // Timing
Table[NIntegrate[sin[x], {x, 0, t}], {t, 0, \[Pi], .01}]; // Timing
```

The output is as expected: The antiderivative is another `InterpolatingFunction`, and the `Integrate` version more than twice as fast as `NIntegrate`:

```
InterpolatingFunction[
    Domain: (0  \[Pi]) Output: scalar
]\[InvisibleApplication](x)

{0.18,Null}

{0.484,Null}
```

Now, let us change the interpolation method to `"BSpline"` in the first line. Then, I get the following output:

```
During evaluation of In[623]:= InterpolatingFunction::unsops: The operation is not supported for InterpolatingFunction[(0   \[Pi]),{5,39,0,{11},{4},0,0,0,0,Automatic,{},{},False},(0   \[Pi]/10    \[Pi]/5 (3 \[Pi])/10    (2 \[Pi])/5 \[Pi]/2 (3 \[Pi])/5 (7 \[Pi])/10    (4 \[Pi])/5 (9 \[Pi])/10    \[Pi]),{BSplineFunction[(0. 3.14159),<>],{}},{Automatic}] that was created with Method -> "Spline". >>

Out[625]= \[Integral]InterpolatingFunction[
    Domain: (0  \[Pi]) Output: scalar
]\[InvisibleApplication](x)\[DifferentialD]x

During evaluation of In[623]:= InterpolatingFunction::unsops: The operation is not supported for InterpolatingFunction[(0   \[Pi]),{5,39,0,{11},{4},0,0,0,0,Automatic,{},{},False},(0   \[Pi]/10    \[Pi]/5 (3 \[Pi])/10    (2 \[Pi])/5 \[Pi]/2 (3 \[Pi])/5 (7 \[Pi])/10    (4 \[Pi])/5 (9 \[Pi])/10    \[Pi]),{BSplineFunction[(0. 3.14159),<>],{}},{Automatic}] that was created with Method -> "Spline". >>

During evaluation of In[623]:= General::stop: Further output of InterpolatingFunction::unsops will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

Out[626]= {2.836,Null}

Out[627]= {1.104,Null}
```

So, the `InterpolatingFunction` can not longer be inspected before evaluation. This results in `NIntegrate` being 2.5 times faster, but six times slower than `Integrate` in the first example!

NB: The error messages go away if I define the function for numerical arguments only, `sin[t_?NumericQ] = ...` See [Failure in integrating from an interpolating function!](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86627).

Question: Is there any feasible solution to improve the performance of the `BSpline` integration? For my data, the interpolation with `Hermite` gives really poor results and cannot be used.

Comment: Antidifferentiation is one of the advantages of Hermite interpolation.  Would `NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == sin[x], y[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, Pi}]` do what want?

Comment: Related: [(Ways to quicken numeric integral over interpolating spline?)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/160622/45431)

Comment: @MichaelE2: Great suggestion, this is awesome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following @MichaelE2's suggestion, I've converted the problem into an ODE:

```
In[1]:=
  sin[t_] = Interpolation[Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, \[Pi], \[Pi]/10}], Method -> "Spline"][t];

  Block[{f},
    f = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == sin[x], y[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, \[Pi]}];
    Table[f[t], {t, 0, \[Pi], .01}];
    ] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[2]= {0.005696,Null}
```

It works equally well for `Spline` and `Hermite` and is orders of magnitude faster than `Integrate` or `NIntegrate`. (I've cleared the caches and even restarted the kernel.)