# How to find the integrand by fitting data - spectrum reconstruction

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, fitting, interpolation, code-review

### Problem statement

I have some experimental data of measurement values vs. temperature.
Now, I want to find the spectrum which causes the measured temperature dependence.

The measurement values are the integrals of

[image]

### The forward calculation

I will now illustrate the problem with an example. There is an yet **unknown** sensitivity spectrum.

```
spectrum[lam_] := Exp[-((lam - 5)/2)^4];
Plot[spectrum[lam], {lam, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {"wavelength", "sensitivity"}]
```

[image]

And there is a **known** spectral intensity

```
intensity[lam_, T_] := 1/(T^4 lam^5) 1/(Exp[1/(lam *T)] - 1)
Plot[Table[intensity[lam, T], {T, 0.03, 0.1, 0.01}] // Evaluate, {lam, 0, 10}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"wavelength", "intensity"}] // Quiet
```

[image]

The measured signals are the areas under these curves

```
Plot[Table[spectrum[lam]*intensity[lam, T], {T, 0.03, 0.1, 0.01}] // Evaluate, {lam, 0, 10}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"wavelength", "intensity"}] // Quiet

data = Table[{T,NIntegrate[spectrum[lam]*intensity[lam, T], {lam, 1, 10}]}, {T, 0.03, 0.1, 0.01}];
ListPlot[data, AxesLabel -> {"temperature", "signal"}]
```

[image]
[image]

### What's the solution?

I thought of nonlinear curve fitting for the control points of an interpolation function as was proposed
[in this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72035/how-to-find-curve-fitting-parameters-without-an-explicit-relation-between-x-and/72037) by Hugh and Alexey Popkov.
Using the sample data, the result should look like the `spectrum[lam]` from above.

But how to make this code work?

```
nOfControlPoints = 5;
controlPoints = Subdivide[1, 10, nOfControlPoints - 1]

model[y : {__Real}] := Interpolation[Transpose[{controlPoints, y}]]
fctn = NIntegrate[model[Array[y, nOfControlPoints]][lam]*intensity[lam, T], {lam, 1, 10}];

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, fctn, Array[y, nOfControlPoints], T]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing obvious mistakes and slightly redesinging the code in order to avoid `NIntegrate` error messages, we get:

```
nOfControlPoints = 5;
controlPoints = Subdivide[1, 10, nOfControlPoints - 1];

Clear[fctn, model];
model[y__Real] := Interpolation[Transpose[{controlPoints, {y}}]]
fctn[{y__Real}][T_Real] := 
  NIntegrate[model[y][lam]*intensity[lam, T], {lam, 1, 10}, 
   Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}];

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, fctn[Array[y, nOfControlPoints]][T], 
  Array[y, nOfControlPoints], T]
```

> [image: screenshot]

Now we can plot the model along with the data:

```
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[nlm["Function"][T], {T, 0.03, 0.1}], Frame -> True]
```

> [image: output]

We see that `NonlinearModelFit` has done its job well.

But the fitted model doesn't reproduce the original spectrum well:

```
Show[Plot[spectrum[lam], {lam, 0, 10}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"wavelength", "sensitivity"}], 
 Plot[Evaluate[model @@ Values@nlm["BestFitParameters"]][lam], {lam, 1, 10}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[{Dashed, Red}]], PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image: output2]

So you can try to increase the number of sample points, try other interpolation method, try to add constraints, better starting values, etc…