# Difference between Fitting Algorithms

Tags: fitting

I am new to *Mathematica*, and I don´t quite understand, what the difference between the fitting algorithms `Fit`, `FindFit`, `LinearModelFit`, `NonLinearModelFit` are.
Why is the syntax so different (`{1,x,x^2}` vs. `a + b x + c x^2`)? 
Which should I prefer for which use-case?
Why can I use a non linear Function like `a + b x + c x^2` in an LinearModelFit? 
I am very confused, I hope you can help me.

Comment: Well the difference between Linear and NonLinear should be clear given the name? :-)

Comment: Fit and FindFit differ in the way they handle the result.   One is meant to cut the chase and give the result, the other provide with the whole statistical analysis.

Comment: some of the differences are historical.

Comment: @chris , by the name, I would say, the difference is, that I just can use LinearFits like a+b*x with LinearModelFit, but when I try to type LinearModelFit[l, 1 + x + x^2, x] in Mathematica, I dont get an error. And does NonLinearModelFit include also the LinearModels, and if true, why should I ever use LinearModelFit over NonLinearModelFit?
And how do Fit and LinearModelFit differ?

Comment: [FindFit \ Properties and Relations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html) section explains a lot. But not everything. And I think question is on topic, at the beginning I was always confused - "great that I can do this in 10 different ways, but which one is appriopriate?"

Comment: As the difference are historical mathematica has built up some level of inconsistency in the paradigm. One has to live with it as far as I can see. More modern functions may supersede older ones but are kept for backward compatibility.

Comment: Ok, and in conclusion, which are the modern functions, and which should i use for wich use-case ?

Comment: @LucaThiede You might want to take a look at the model you are trying to fit first to help in your decision. I summarized a few thoughts that may dispel some confusion in an answer below. Hope it helps.

Comment: [Strongly related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61340/7167)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Luca, I think that you may be misunderstanding the meaning of "linear" in the names of those functions, and in general in reference to linear models.

Just to make sure that we agree on the nomenclature here, in a fitting model you have parameters, and predictor variables. For instance, in a simple quadratic model such as `y = a x^2 + b x + c` we typically understand `a`, `b`, `c` as the parameters, and `x` as the predictor variable.

***Linear*** models are those models in which the predicted value (e.g. `y` in our example) depends linearly ***on the parameters of the model***. It doesn't matter whether the relationship between `y` and `x` is linear. For instance, the model above is linear. This following model is also linear: `y = a Sin[x^2]`. Model fitting is a search for the parameters, so linear parameter relationships lead to models that are easier to deal with computationally, and in some cases to closed-form solutions to the regression problem.

***Non-linear models*** are those in which the predicted value depends on the parameters in a non-linear fashion. For instance: `y = Sin[a] x` is non linear because the predicted value depends non-linearly on the value of the parameter `a` (even though the predicted value depends linearly on `x`!).

In addition to the interesting reasons mentioned by the commenters to your question, which I think shed some light on the issue as well, the existence of multiple fitting functions also reflects this fundamental divide.

On the basis of my (limited) experience, here is how I view the most common fitting functions:

- [`Fit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fit.html) is the oldest of the bunch; it carries out *linear* model fitting by linearly combining a list of base functions you explicitly indicate. I don't tend to use it much, since the majority of models I fit to are non-linear.
- [`FindFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html) is newer; it is capable of both *linear* and *non-linear* fitting. You feed it the explicit form of the fitting model directly. I find this very intuitive to use.
- [`NonlinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html) accomplishes the same results as `FindFit` and it shares the same syntax. In addition to the fitted model, it also gives you access to a wealth of fitting descriptors: goodness of fit estimates, prediction intervals, residuals, just to name a few. You could think of it as a `FindFit` "on steroids". It would be really worth your time to take a look at the many options available for this function ("Details and Options" section of its documentation).
- `FindFit` is also faster than `NonlinearModelFit`: the former is implemented in fast numerical code within the kernel; the latter is written entirely in top-level code, i.e. using *Mathematica* expressions, and it internally calls `FindFit` to do the heavy lifting anyway (@OleksandrR. talked about this point more authoritatively in [his answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72455/27951) regarding compiled versions of the fitting routines).

Comment: Oh ok, my fault. And can I use Fit and FindFit also for non linear fitting?

Comment: @LucaThiede Good point. Let me add something to that respect to the answer.

Comment: Ok, and I assume that LinearModelFit is the same as NonLinearModelFit, but limited to the Linear Models, whereas NonLinearModelFit is for everything, is that correct? Has LinearModelFit any advantage over the NonLinearModelFit?

Comment: @LucaThiede You are correct on the `Linear` vs `Nonlinear` functions. Linear models can typically be solved deterministically (i.e. there is a closed-form solution to find the best fit parameters), whereas non-linear models require an iterative process, so if your model is linear the functions specifically geared to the linear models are going to be faster and more reliable. Of course, if your model is *not* linear, then you are stuck with the iterative processes.