# NonlinearModelFit and plot with multiple parameters function

Tags: plotting, fitting, nonlinear

i ve got quite simple function:

$f(t) = x1 * a(t) + x2 * b(t)$

and table of results like this one:

```
t | f(t) | a(t) | b(t)
----------------------
1 |  2   |   5  |  3
----------------------
2 |  4   |   9  | -4 
----------------------
3 |  10  |  12  | 5
----------------------
```

And I need this to solve with NonlinearModelFit, Ive looked across the internet, but I was not able to find solve and plot function like this..

My (wrong, not functionall solution):

```
data = {{2,5,3}, {4,9,-4}, {10,12,5}
// This line will ends with error: Number of coordinates (3) is not equal to the number of variables (2).
nls  = NonlinearModelFit[data, x1*y + x2*x, {{y, 0.3}, {x, -0.24}}, {y,z}} 

// Next thing is problem with plot.. offcourse i can do sth like this:
f = { {1, 2}, {2,4}, {3, 10}}

// This plot is incomplete, because I was no able to find
// how to write x in data array :(
Show[ListPlot[f], Plot[nls[t,x,y], ...
```

I bet someone will find solution immediatelly, but Iam new in Mathematica.. Sorry for the dataset (i cant send full dataset, its bigger).

Thanks

EDIT:

Thank you very much to @jens_bo, I solve that with his help and his response. The main problem was caused by sharing variables across notebooks in mathematica... restart mathematica and everything works great :)

Comment: Your model is manifestly linear, so there's no need for the elaboration of a nonlinear fit.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: do you know what kind of functions a(t) and b(t) are?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Dont worry, Iam using stackoverflow and Iam not a begginer on stackxxx forums ;)

Comment: @jens_bo a(t) and b(t) is meassurment data in the "T" time, I have a lot of data a(t) and b(t) but only few f(t), Imagine like continuos meassurment of load server nad free capacity of memory (per 1 second), but just few times of load your web application (per 1 minute) and you´re looking for relation between them... It´s not good example and Iam looking for sth quite different, but the idea is almost the same.

Comment: @JanStrnádek You may need to share a larger and more realistic data set, and possibly disclose the real application you have in mind. I for one don't think I could help you much further otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: You should check if the code I am using matches your problem, since I had to guess some unclear parts (parenthesis and x,y,z naming).

Since I don't know anything about $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ I threat $f(t)$ as a function of two unknowns $a$ and $b$, or $f(a,b)$.

If we want to fit the data we can use `NonlinearFit`, but
`NonlinearFit` takes data of the form `{{x11,x12,...,y1},{x21,x22,...,y2},...}}` if you have multiple variables. So in your case that would be `{{a(t1),b(t1),f(t1)},{a(t2),b(t2),f(t2)},...}`, so:

```
data = {{5, 3, 2}, {9, -4, 4}, {12, 5, 10}};

nls = NonlinearModelFit[data, x1*a + x2*b, {{x1, 0.3}, {x2, -0.24}}, {a, b}]
```

Now, in order to check the fit we can use a 3D plot (since your function only depends on two variables).

```
Show[
     ListPointPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize -> .025]], 
     Plot3D[nls[a, b], {a, -15, 15}, {b, -15, 15},PlotStyle ->Opacity[.75]]
    ]
```

gives you:

[image]

If you have more than two dependencies or you just want to see the deviations of the model from the data in a more presentable (2D) way, you can use the residuals of the fit and maybe plot them vs. the times $t$.

```
times = {1, 2, 3};
ListPlot[Transpose@{times, nls["FitResiduals"]}, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you too, but your solution not working, Iam getting an error General::ivar: "{{-26.92` Inverse", I google it but still not sure if its problem of "notation" or data? :(

Comment: Where did you get this error? Does it work with the data you posted here?

Comment: I try your example, Ive just run: data = {{5, 3, 2}, {9, -4, 4}, {12, 5, 10}};
nls = NonlinearModelFit[data, x1*a + x2*b, {{x1, 0.3}, {x2, -0.24}}, {a, b}] and this error occurs, the same thing happens with my original data or with just data = {{5, 3, 2}}...

Comment: Also you can plot f(t) and the f(t) according to the fit using the residuals, if that's what you need instead of just the quality of the fit.

Comment: The error does not occur for me. Maybe start with a fresh kernel (new mathematica session)? Maybe you are using some of the variables somewhere else...

Comment: Plotting is the next step, but still Iam no able to find coefficients ... :( Next thing, I dont need 3D plot.. this is "data1 + data2 => data3". Iam looking between relations of 3 types meassured data, the equation (a*x1 + b*x2) is correct, so its more like 3 lines in one 2d chart.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23507/discussion-between-jens-bo-and-jan-strnadek).

Answer (score 3):

In the format you propose, the dependence of $f$ on $t$ is left implicit in your model. $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ seem to be some quadratic function of $t$, but as @jens_bo mentioned, you need to tell us or find out more about $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ to obtain a fit of $f$ as a function of $t$.

**Data format:** Data needs to be presented to all fitting functions as a list of data points, each data point being itself a list of numbers, with the values of the independent variables coming first, and the dependent variable last. For example, see this format specified in the [documentation page for `NonLinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html). In other words, data to be fit needs to conform to the pattern `{{x1 , y1, f1}, {x2 , y2, f2}, ...}`. Your data has the value of $f$ first instead.

In this case, it would be easy to fix this by hand, but a programmatic solution could be the following:

```
data = {{2, 5, 3}, {4, 9, -4}, {10, 12, 5}}
rearrangeddata = Transpose@RotateLeft[Transpose@data, 1]

(* Out: {{5, 3, 2}, {9, -4, 4}, {12, 5, 10}}, i.e.

a    b    f
-----------
5    3    2
9   -4    4
12   5   10

*)
```

**Fitting:** In all cases, the *functions depend linearly on the parameters* (see also [my answer to question 80998](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/81002/27951) on the distinction between non-linear and linear fitting), so you don't need to carry out an iterative non-linear fit: a linear model will suffice.

You could then take two approaches to fitting this function. You could obtain a fit of $f$ as a function of variables $a$ and $b$, disregarding their dependence on $t$. $f(a,b)=x1\ a+x2\ b$ from your data.

```
linearmodelfit = Fit[rearrangeddata, {y, x}, {y, x}]

(* Out: 0.321159 x + 0.613899 y *)
```

Alternatively, you could obtain a fit of $f$ as a function of the single variable $t$. Even though $f\propto t^2$, the model itself is still linear, so again we don't need to use `NonlinearModelFit`; `LinearModelFit` will do just fine.

```
LinearModelFit[{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 10}}, {t, t^2}, x][t]

(* Out: 4 - 4 t + 2 t^2 *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, whole table is Meassurment data in the time "T", so Ive got 3 values for every time "t" and i need aproximate function f(t) = x1*a(t) + x2*b(t). Thats the second problem with plot, I need to draw that function... For the plot of the result of NonlinearModelFit, I probably can provide a function a(t) and b(t) (It can be some kind of approximation, because Ive got a lot of data for a(t) and b(t) but ive got a few values for f(t))...

Comment: @Jan, consider following Marco's advice to use `LinearModelFit[]` instead; unless you have a genuinely nonlinear model, you don't need such am expensive function.