# How to plot a characteristic curve for silicon diode

Tags: plotting, fitting, homework

There is a figure given that shows the relation between Forward current(y axis) and forward Voltage (x axis ) for a forward biased diode, with the given formula

$$If(forward current)= I0*e^{(k*q*T*Vf)/n}$$

Where $n=2, q=1.6*10^-19 , k=1.3805*10^-23$, Vf is the forward voltage and i am guessing T is the temperature.

The data points are given for If and for Vf. I need to use `ListPlot` to model the data as a function and then plot the characteristic curve for the silicon diode.

I don’t know what steps i need to provide (or what program i need to construct) in order to be able to plot a perfect curve for the diode so that when i try to insert the data points on the plotted curve they fit or are close.

I used `Interpolation` to function the data points firstly and then i used list plot command to plot the data points list.
Then when i used plot command to plot the points given to find the curve, it keeps giving error! How do i proceed?

```
IF = {0.0, 0.0, 0.02, 0.25, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13}
VF = {0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.576, 0.603, 0.624, 0.636, 0.646, 0.654, 0.661, 0.667, 0.671, 0.676, 0.681, 0.684}
Riffle[VF, IF]
data = Partition[%, 2]

f1 = Interpolation[data]

PLOT1 = ListPlot[f1, Joined -> False, PlotRange -> {{0.0, 1.0}, {0, 13}}, PlotStyle -> {Red}, PlotMarkers -> {Style["\[CircleDot]", Red, Smaller]}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"VF (volt)", "IF(aM)"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black]]

CurveThickness = 0.05

PLOT2 = Plot[f1[VF], {VF, 0.0, 1.0}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"VF (volt)", "IF (aM)"}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Black], 
PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[CurveThickness]}]
```

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried.

Comment: how do i show that on here using mathematica?

Comment: @JohnDoty is the code i entered correct? i am just trying to plot the characteristic curve for the diode at given data points. i tried using Fit Command but the formula/ equation i was required to enter didnt have enough information.

Comment: I think the idea of the problem might be for you to **fit** the points to the model given by the formula you posted. Look into `NonlinearModelFit`. Then you can plot your raw data with `ListPlot`, the fit you found with `Plot`, and combine the two together using `Show`.

Comment: @MarcoB can u just show me how? i tried using the nlmf command letting the forward voltage be the variable but it didnt give any curve.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra value of `IF` for the number of values of `VF` you had, so I am commenting out the last one in your data. Also, rather than `Riffle` and `Partition`, I'd obtain the same thing with `Transpose`.

```
IF = {0., 0., 0.02, 0.25, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12(*, 13*)};
VF = {0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.576, 0.603, 0.624, 0.636, 0.646, 
      0.654, 0.661, 0.667, 0.671, 0.676, 0.681, 0.684};
data = Transpose[{VF, IF}];

(* given parameter values *)
CurveThickness = 0.05
n = 2;
q = 1.6*^-19;
k = 1.3805*^-23;

(* Carry out the non-linear fit of data to your model *)
nlmf = NonlinearModelFit[data, i0 Exp[k q T Vf/n], {i0, T}, Vf];

(* generate and combine the two plots               *)
(* note that shared options have been moved to Show *) 
(* rather than duplicating them in both plots       *)
Show[
  (* plotting the results of the fit *)
  Plot[
    nlmf[Vf], {Vf, 0, 1}, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[CurveThickness]]
  ],
  (* plotting the raw data *)
  ListPlot[
    data, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.02], Red], 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Black]
  ],
  PlotRange -> {{0.0, 1.0}, {0, 13}},
  Frame -> True,
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black], 
  FrameLabel -> {"VF (volt)", "IF(aM)"}
]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: its a perfect fit! wow that rarely happens in practicals. btw whats the difference if i had used Interpolation instead of NonLinearModelFit? why not use Fit only ?

Comment: @Haneen `Interpolation` and fitting are conceptually different: an interpolation always goes through the points you feed it, by definition: that's what it's supposed to do! A fit will find the best parameter values in a given model to get as close as possible to your data, but typically may not go through them exactly. I wonder if this is "synthetic" data, i.e. made up by whoever wrote the problem, or really experimental values.

Comment: @Haneen Finally, `Fit` would have given the same results, but `NonlinearModelFit` is the more modern version that given you access to an easier to use solution and to statistics on the fit "for free". See this for further details: [Difference between Fitting Algorithms](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/81002/27951).

Comment: oh thank you so much, your definitions cleared out everything.