# Slow-down encountered when using NMinimize with a compiled function

Tags: mathematical-optimization, symbolic, compile, performance-tuning, scaling

I'm minimizing a large function. Evaluating the function is very slow symbolically but using Compile I can get ~100x speed-up on this step. However, despite this, the NMinimize process is only marginally faster for large equations, and very much slower for small ones.

Is there a way to pass NMinimize the information it would normally get from a symbolic function but in compiled form? An example in this would be passing the function and its Jacobian to a root finder, avoiding the need to use finite differences.

Here is the example I'm working on. Any comments/pedantry as to how I've written this would also be appreciated; I still have no idea about the best ways to do things, and have trouble forcing/maintaining consistency.

```
centralangle[{q1_, p1_}, {q2_, p2_}] := 
  ArcCos[Sin[q1] Sin[q2] + Cos[q1] Cos[q2] Cos[p1 - p2]];
energy[qp_, i_, max_] := 
  Sum[If[s == i, 0, (centralangle[qp[[i]], qp[[s]]])^-1], {s, 1, max}];
totalenergy[qp_, max_] := Sum[energy[qp, i, max], {i, 1, max}]/2;
```

Now test this for 10 particles, and I find the symbolic minimization to be ~6x faster

```
ClearAll[q, p]
max = 10;
qp = Table[Unique[{q, p}], {max}];
qpFlat = Flatten[qp];
eqn = totalenergy[qp, max];
ceqn = Compile[Evaluate[{#, _Real} & /@ qpFlat], Evaluate[eqn], 
  "RuntimeOptions" -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}];
Timing[
 NMinimize[eqn, qpFlat];
 ]
Timing[
 NMinimize[ceqn[Sequence @@ qpFlat], qpFlat];
 ]



{0.374402, Null}(symbolic)
{2.246414, Null}(compiled)
```

Although for 100 particles, I find single evaluations ~100x faster when compiled

```
ClearAll[q, p]
max = 100;
qp = Table[Unique[{q, p}], {max}];
qpFlat = Flatten[qp];
eqn = totalenergy[qp, max];
ceqn = Compile[Evaluate[{#, _Real} & /@ qpFlat], Evaluate[eqn], 
  "RuntimeOptions" -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}];

init = RandomReal[1., 2 max];
Timing[
 eqn /. Table[qpFlat[[i]] -> init[[i]], {i, 1, 2 max}];
 ]
Timing[
 ceqn[Sequence @@ init];
 ]



{1.279208, Null}(symbolic)
{0.015600, Null}(compiled)
```

The minimization for 100 particles is overall 1.5x faster for the compiled function, clearly as a trade-off between whatever is going on here.

Comment: Do you have to use global optimization (`NMinimize`) rather than local (`FindMinimum`)? Any information you have such as good initial guesses will help speed up the problem.

Comment: FindMinimum produces rather poor results, and would surely suffer from the same slowing-down that it's buddy does. I'll have another go and see if there's a good initial point I can use though.

Comment: `NMinimize` does not require (and cannot accept) gradients. All its methods are direct search algorithms; there is no more information required than a black box function. If the Nelder-Mead method would be sufficient for you, perhaps you might like to try [a compiled implementation of that](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/shaving-the-last-50-ms-off-nminimize/4877#4877).

Comment: Can you explain why NMinimize would be so much slower using a compiled function?

Comment: Evaluate here simply converts the symbol eqn to the equation it represents. You can see the code has compiled correctly by running the additional code Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]; CompilePrint[ceqn].

The second part of my question shows major speed up in single evaluations of the equation, which further evidences correct compilation.

Comment: I am not sure. Your function looks fine. I don't have time at the moment to investigate further, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

### Update

In a comment Oleksandr pointed out that the number of iterations may be having an effect. This is evident from running the following code:

```
max = 10;
qp = Table[Unique[{q, p}], {max}];
qpFlat = Flatten[qp];
eqn = totalenergy[qp, max];
ceqn = Compile[Evaluate[{#, _Real} & /@ qpFlat], Evaluate[eqn], 
   "RuntimeOptions" -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}];

Block[{i = 0}, 
  r1 = NMinimize[eqn, qpFlat, 
    Method -> {Automatic, RandomSeed -> 1}, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> i++]; 
  i] // AbsoluteTiming

(* Average from 10 runs: 0.399 seconds, 303 evaluations *)

Block[{i = 0}, 
  r2 = NMinimize[ceqn[Sequence @@ qpFlat], qpFlat, 
    Method -> {Automatic, RandomSeed -> 1}, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> i++]; 
  i] // AbsoluteTiming

(* Average from 10 runs: 3.25 seconds, 3056 evaluations *)
```

For `max = 50`, the timings are

```
(* Uncompiled: 15.94 seconds, 521 evaluations *)
(* Compiled: 19.47 seconds, 5000 evaluations *)
```

Quite why the compiled function needs 10x more evaluations I'm currently not sure...

---

### Original answer

It seems that the value of the `WorkingPrecision` option in `NMinimize` has an effect on the performance of the two functions.

Using the OP's definitions for `eqn`, `ceqn` and `qpFlat`, I tried the following. 
The random seed is set to 1 to ensure the returned parameters are the same.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 r1 = NMinimize[eqn, qpFlat, 
    Method -> {"NelderMead", RandomSeed -> 1}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 10];]
(* 3.119 seconds *)

AbsoluteTiming[
 r2 = NMinimize[ceqn[Sequence @@ qpFlat], qpFlat, 
    Method -> {"NelderMead", RandomSeed -> 1}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 10];]
(* 0.311 seconds *)

Abs@(First@r1 - First@r2)
(* 6.6*10^-7 : this is the difference in the objective function value *)
```

Changing back to `WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision`, which is the default, I find that the compiled version takes longer than the uncompiled version, which is what the OP found.

Comment: Are you sure you ran this after eqn had been assigned? The compilation works and prints correctly if you run the above code followed by

Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"];
CompilePrint[ceqn]

If it did not, we would see no change in the speed of single evaluations as we do at the bottom of my question.

Comment: @user5751 have updated the answer having investigated the effect of `WorkingPrecision`...

Comment: It has some effect but the difference is not large. Compare e.g. `Method -> {Automatic, RandomSeed -> 1}, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision` with `Method -> {Automatic, RandomSeed -> 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 10`, both for the compiled funciton. I think this is consistent with fewer iterations being performed more than anything else.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I was thinking the same...see my updated answer.