# Custom Methods for NMinimize/NonLinearModelFit

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting, implementation-details

Is there a way to write custom methods for `NonLinearModelFit` or `NMinimize`?

To give background, I currently have a batch of code that uses `NonLinearModelFit` with `NMinimize` as the method to do constrained optimization. The interface I developed exposes all the method options and suboptions for `NMinimize` for user selection.

Since writing that code I've been writing my own algorithms for multi-objective optimization (MOO) which I think would perform quite well. However, with the old code being built around the structure of the `FittedModel` construct that `NonLinearModelFit` returns, I would need to wrap my algorithms in code that produces the same structured output. Not impossible, but really annoying.

So my hope is that maybe there is a way that I can create custom methods for either `NMinimize` or `NonLinearModelFit` so that Mathematica can pass along the `FittedModel` and reduce development time.

Comment: Related - [Compiled version of Nelder-Mead](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/shaving-the-last-50-ms-off-nminimize)

Comment: I wonder if you would be willing to share some more details of your implementation. I have been developing a fitting routine for experimental data that must be deconvoluted from a known instrumental response function. I ended up having to write my own objective function, and `NMinimize`'s Nelder-Mead algorithm. It works, but it's very sensitive to starting values, and it is sluggish even in the simplest of cases. I'd love to be able to still use `NonlinearModelFit` for its rich statistical output, but I couldn't make it work. I'd very much appreciate knowing more about your approach!

Comment: @MarcoB Honestly,there wasn't a whole lot of messing around that was needed to get it to work. I used the following option: `Method -> {"NMinimize", StepMonitor :> steps++, 
  EvaluationMonitor :> evals++, Method -> CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "method"}]}` and that took care of it. I used `TaggingRules` because the code produces a pallet that can be used independent of the underlying notebook being saved. Most of the code is preparing the data and constraints to be inserted into `NonLinearModelFit`. We've always had very consistent results with the NelderMead method.

Comment: That is very interesting, thank you! I'll wade through the method parameters you shared and see what I can make of those... In the meantime, I hope that your question might pique the fancy of somebody more knowledgeable.

Comment: @MarcoB I guess to make it a little clearer, these are the parameters fed into method: `"method" -> {"NelderMead", "ContractRatio" -> 0.5, 
  "ExpandRatio" -> 2.0, "InitialPoints" -> Automatic, 
  "PenaltyFunction" -> Automatic, "PostProcess" -> Automatic, 
  "RandomSeed" -> 0, "ReflectRatio" -> 1.0, "ShrinkRatio" -> 0.5, 
  "Tolerance" -> 0.001`, but these are the default values for the NelderMead algorithm so nothing revelatory. At least this way you know what the `"method"` `TaggingRules` is referencing. As I hinted to earlier, all these are exposed through a custom UI