# NMinimize Example from Wolfram Documentation Center

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Here is the third example of NMinimize function from Wolfram Documentation Center at Possible Issues section.

```
NMinimize[-x Sin[x] + 3 Cos[x] + x/1000, {x, -100, 100}]
(*  {-26.9735,{x -> 26.8514}}  *)
```

With Mathematica 10.1, I copied and run it,the result was:

```
{-221.74, {x -> -221.5}}
```

I am so confused about the two different results with the range of `{x,-100,100}`.

Any help?

Comment: Clearly, something was changed in the internal implementation. More worryingly, the result is clearly out of bounds. Try adding the constraint as part of the first argument instead, and report back.

Comment: Mathematica 10.1, 10.0.2, 9.0.1, 8.0.2 gives the same result.

Comment: Note that `{x, -100, 100}` specifies a *starting interval*, not a constraint.  I see nothing wrong with a result that is better than the incorrect output in the documentation. (That is, the output result in the documentation file is not the result of the input -- one of several such errors in the documentation pages, by the way.)

Comment: @Felix and OP: can you mention the OS you're using, for reference?

Comment: You can see what's going on under the hood with ``Block[{Optimization`NMinimizeDump`$DiagnosticLevel = 3 (* 0-6 *)}, NMinimize[-x Sin[x] + 3 Cos[x] + x/1000, {x, -100, 100}]]``.  See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4708 for details.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. 10.1(OS X10.11), 10.0.2(OS X10.11),9.0.1and 8.0.2 (Windows XP); 7.0.1(Win XP) gives `{-2148.27, {x -> 2150.42}}`; 6.0.3 (Win XP) gives `{-26.9735, {x -> 26.8514}}` (which is the only one same as the doc); 5.2 (win xp) gives `{-33.2609, {x -> -33.107}}`

Comment: @MichaelE2  it seems that the `Minimize` doc with "possible issues" was introduced in version 6, and at that time it is the same with mma's result. They just didn't change the doc when they changed the implementation.

Comment: @Felix I suspected something like that.  There are a few other instances in docs that I've come across, but I just ignore them unless they flat-out don't work.

Comment: @incognito007, You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers.

Comment: @Michael E2, Thank your editing. A few terms the Woflram used are varaible, rectangular initial region and starting interval with constraint.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by the comments by [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) the new behavior is fine and still illustrates how specifying an initial interval can improve the optimum found.

The specific change is due to improvements in the implementation, chiefly owing to the `Automatic` method strategy being switched from `"NelderMead"` to `"DifferentialEvolution"` for one-dimensional problems, which happened around version 7.0.1 (while the old result cannot be currently replicated by setting `Method -> "NelderMead"`, that's likely due to further tweaks to initial points generation).

I will follow up with the appropriate people to make sure this example is reevaluated in the documentation (**done as of version 10.3.0**).