# Examples of a large Mathematica construction?

Tags: programming, example

I'm pretty new to Mathematica, and in trying to find examples of good Mathematica programming, it always seems that solutions to a problem can be solved with hardly any lines of code. Of course this is a great thing, but I am curious to see some examples of Mathematica in use in a "large scale" project/creation. Does anybody have any examples they could link me to?

Comment: There are several large projects/packages: http://packagedata.net/  Examples: [Combinatorica](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~skiena/combinatorica/) [xAct](http://www.xact.es/) [Theorema](http://www.risc.jku.at/research/theorema/software/) [SciDraw](http://scidraw.nd.edu/) [RISCErgoSum](http://www.risc.jku.at/research/combinat/software/ergosum/index.html) [xCellerator](http://www.cellerator.org/) [Neuoritca](https://github.com/noahbenson/Neurotica) [FeynCalc](https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc) [RUBI](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/) and many others.  Keep browsing http://packagedata.net/

Comment: I heartily second @Szabolcs suggestion; additionally you may also be interested in the FAQ [Where can I find examples of good *Mathematica* programming practice](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/27951) on this site.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "large", but this is moderately so: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4877