# NMinimize : Finding which method was used

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Is it possible to find out which method Mathematica used when using the NMinimize method? Ie, either Nelder-Mead, differential evolution, etc...

Thanks.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html). "With the default method, NMinimize picks which method to use based on the type of problem. If the objective function and constraints are linear, LinearProgramming is used. If there are integer variables, or if the head of the objective function is not a numeric function, differential evolution is used. For everything else, it uses Nelder–Mead, but if Nelder–Mead does poorly, it switches to differential evolution."

Comment: Hi. Yes. I read that too. The problem is I don’t know if Nelder-Mead is “doing poorly”!

Comment: Also relevant is [this answer from Oleksandr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4708/27951).