# Is any attempt to implement by hand built-in functions reasonable?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, performance-tuning

There are a lot of functions that are related to numerical computation of integrals, numerical solutions of algebraic/differential equations, etc. In such functions there a lot of different methods (for instance, `NIntegrate` and  `NDSolve` contain many strategies/methods).

Question: **Can I safely assume that these built-in functions and methods (to be more specific, consider** `NIntegrate` **and** `NDsolve` **, and their methods) are completely optimized and tuned? So, any attempt to realize this functions by hand is slower than existing realization?**

To be more specific, let me consider the numerical solution of a differential equation with 4-th order Runge-Kutta method. In principle, I can realize by hand such scheme and perform the explicit performance comparison between my code and `NDsolve` with with `Method->"ExplicitRungeKutta"` but the question is more general.

Can anyone provide the references/examples where this question is discussed? My interest is mostly about `NIntegrate` and `NDSolve`, then about `RandomFunction`.

Comment: I have managed to surpass Mathematica's speed dramatically by writing specialized C code. Mathematica's functions seem to be generic, but likely also written in C. Matching their speed by writing Mathematica code does not seem likely to me.

Comment: This is very interesting reading https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/shaving-the-last-50-ms-off-nminimize In short, sometimes you can but if you spend one week to shave 50 ms is it worth it for a few times use?

Comment: I've written Mathematica code to surpass Mathematica's built-in functions.  But I'm simply stating it's possible and do not wish to go into details.

Comment: It depends heavily on just how much work has gone into optimizing the built in code in terms of algorithm(s) used, heuristics for switching methods and/or parameter values, etc. Difficult to give a general response.