# Getting standard errors (Hessian matrix) from optimization with constraints

Tags: mathematical-optimization

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
link1 = {84, 54, 36, 21};
klink1 = 4;
skinks = {56, 19, 28, 18, 24, 14, 9};
kskinks = 7;


mylikBetaBin[data_, kdata_, f0_, alpha_, beta_] := Module[
    {K, pj, fj, j, N, loglik, above, below},

    K = kdata;
    pj = Table[
        Binomial[K, j]*
        Beta[alpha + j, K - j + beta]/
        Beta[alpha, beta], {j, 0, K}
    ];

    fj = Prepend[data, f0];

    N = Sum[fj[[j]], {j, 1, Length[fj]}];
    above = LogGamma[N + 1];
    below = Sum[LogGamma[fj[[j]] + 1], {j, 1, Length[fj]}];
    loglik = fj.Log[pj];

    loglik = above - below + loglik
]

(*mylikBetaBin[link1, klink1, 37, 0.8, 0.3]*)

testfun[f0_, alpha_, beta_] := 
mylikBetaBin[skinks, kskinks, f0, alpha, beta];

(*testfun[165.178,0.573,1.576]*)

NMaximize[
    {testfun[f0, alpha, beta], 
    f0 >= 0 && alpha >= 0 && beta >= 0},
    {f0, alpha, beta},
    Method -> {"RandomSearch", "SearchPoints" -> 250}
]
```

I am new to *Mathematica*. I need to do some (global) optimization with constraints. This is a simple example I just managed to get it work! (finally)

I want to know if I am doing the right thing? Is `NMaximize` the function to use?

But the main question is, is there an optimizer will give me the standard errors (Hessian evaluated at these points)?

If not, how would I get them?

Comment: Just in case you haven't read it http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html

Comment: There's also: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43513/how-to-work-with-experimentalnumericalfunction/44890#44890

Comment: And (related) http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54877/13162

Comment: Thanks blochwave! I had read two of the links you provided. I was hoping that some optimizer will have an 'option' I can just switch on to have the standard errors (or just HESSIAN). But it seems not though Hessian is most commonly 'desired' when optimization, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ans=NMaximize[
    {testfun[f0, alpha, beta], 
    f0 >= 0 && alpha >= 0 && beta >= 0},
    {f0, alpha, beta},
    Method -> {"RandomSearch", "SearchPoints" -> 200}
]


he = D[testfun[f0, alpha, beta], {{f0, alpha, beta}, 2}]

he /. ans[[2]] // MatrixForm

Inverse[%]
Diagonal[-%]
Sqrt[%]
```

After some trial and error, I believe I found 'a' way to do this.

If anyone has a better solution, please let me know.
Thanks!