# Does LinearSolve know that I gave it a Sparse lower triangular matrix?

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra, implementation-details, sparse-arrays

Let $\mathbf L$ be a nonsingular numeric (non-symbolic) large, lower triangular sparse matrix.  Let $\mathbf b$ be an appropriately sized vector.  I want to solve $\mathbf L\mathbf x=\mathbf b$.

Does `LinearSolve` know that it can perform backsubstitution?  There is an  undocumented function called `LUBackSubstitution`. Wolfram's help website says [its functionality has been superseded by `LinearSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LUBackSubstitution.html). Is this true for sparse arrays as well?

Edit: All the responses so far have only addressed dense matrices, I was only interested in sparse matrices.

Comment: Re: `LUBackSubstitution[]`: [it used to be documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v4/RefGuide/LUBackSubstitution.html), but it was quietly shuffled off to the background after `LinearSolveFunction[]` (which does store the decomposed matrix in the same format internally) became available. I imagine `LinearSolve[]` is smart enough to detect triangular matrices.

Comment: Another note: as is well-known, *Mathematica* uses LAPACK behind the scenes. In relation to this, there is the function ``LinearAlgebra`LAPACK`LATRS[]``, which, though undocumented in *Mathematica*, is [familiar to LAPACK users](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.1.1/html/dlatrs.f.html). The usage is a bit cumbersome, tho.

Comment: There is also the BLAS function ``LinearAlgebra`BLAS`TRSV[]``, which might be used internally by `LinearSolveFunction[]`.

Comment: I tried using Oleksandr's trick [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3221) to see if I could intercept any calls from either of the two suspects I gave above. Unfortunately, `LinearSolve[]` is apparently opaque to this.

Comment: @rhermans While I am grateful for all the work people did in attempting to answer my question, neither of the responses uses a `SparseArray`.  This is fundamental to my question.  I should have put that in the title.  Also this problem come from the discretization of a PDE so $1000 \times 1000$ would actually be on the "small" end of things.  The dimension of the problem will be more like $100,000\times 100,000$.  How should I address this?

Comment: "I should have put that in the title." - then edit your question to say so.

Comment: Is your sparse lower triangular matrix banded, or does it have a more complicated structure? Can you give a (small-ish) example of what you're dealing with?

Comment: @J.M.  I am impressed and grateful for the work you did.  Since I am no longer terribly interested in the answer to this question, I propose to  change the question to match your response instead.  What do you think of this?

Comment: That's your call, I'd say. I certainly wouldn't object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I decided to do the test I proposed in a comment myself. It is known that `LinearSolve[]`, when applied to just a matrix, generates a `LinearSolveFunction[]` that internally stores the LU decomposition of a matrix. I feel that it would be more accurate for timing purposes to decouple the decomposition and backsubstitution phases, and take the timings only on the backsubstitution.

With that,

```
(* LU-decomposed matrices *)
lstab = Table[LinearSolve[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {k, k}]],
              {k, 100, 1000, 100}];

(* random vectors with matching dimensions *)
vecs = Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], k], {k, 100, 1000, 100}];

(* extract and transpose upper triangular factors for lower triangular example *)
tritab = Composition[LinearSolve, Transpose] /@ Through[lstab["getU"]];

(* ...and, timing! *)
timeFull = Table[{100 n, RepeatedTiming[lstab[[n]] @ vecs[[n]], .1][[1]]}, {n, 10}];
timeTri = Table[{100 n, RepeatedTiming[tritab[[n]] @ vecs[[n]], .1][[1]]}, {n, 10}];

ListLinePlot[{Legended[timeTri, "lower triangular"], 
              Legended[timeFull, "full matrix"]},
             PlotMarkers -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: lower triangular versus full solves]

At the very least, we can guess that the backsubstitution behind the scenes is faster in the lower triangular case than in the full case, since the latter has to do two of them.

---

As a further comparison, I tried comparing the use of `LinearSolve[]` on a lower triangular matrix against a direct call to the internal BLAS function [`*TRSV`](http://www.netlib.org/blas/dtrsv.f):

```
(* lower triangular matrices *)
trimat = Transpose /@ Through[lstab["getU"]];

(* timing BLAS calls *)
timeBLAS = Table[{100 n, RepeatedTiming[
                 Block[{mat = trimat[[n]], x = vecs[[n]]}, 
                       LinearAlgebra`BLAS`TRSV["L", "N", "N", mat, x]], .1][[1]]},
                 {n, 10}];

(* timing LinearSolve[] calls *)
timeTri = Table[{100 n, RepeatedTiming[tritab[[n]]@vecs[[n]], .1][[1]]}, {n, 10}];

ListLinePlot[{Legended[timeTri, "LinearSolve"], 
              Legended[timeBLAS, "BLAS"]},
             PlotMarkers -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: LinearSolve[] versus BLAS]

If the overhead of `LinearSolve[]` is a concern, I suppose a direct BLAS call can be used instead.

Comment: Although I can achieve many functions by ``?LinearAlgebra`*`` in the context `LinearAlgebra`, I cannot use these functions owning to that they are undocumented. So J.M. , could you tell me how did you know the usage of these function? thanks.

Comment: I'm familiar with BLAS and LAPACK from using them in Fortran. It was merely a matter of matching what I knew about Fortran usage to how it might be called in *Mathematica*.

Comment: OK, @J.M. thanks for your explonation I never learned `Fortran`. I only learned the _Visual Basic_, C and _Python_.

Comment: @thank_you Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100486/how-to-know-the-usage-of-undocumented-function-like-linearalgebrablas)?

Answer (score 3):

Weird. It seems that `LinearSolve` takes *longer* for a triangular matrix.

```
(* create a well-conditioned random lower triangular matrix *)
rndLowerTriangular[n_] :=
 Normal[SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; i > j -> .1, {i_, i_} -> 10}, {n, 
     n}]*RandomReal[{1, 2}, {n, n}]]

randomProblem[n_] := 
 LinearSolve[rndLowerTriangular[n], RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n]]

Monitor[time = 
   Table[{n, RepeatedTiming[randomProblem[n], .1][[1]]}, {n, 100, 
     1000, 100}], n];

randomProblemFull[n_] := 
 LinearSolve[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n]]

Monitor[timeFull = 
   Table[{n, RepeatedTiming[randomProblemFull[n], .1][[1]]}, {n, 100, 
     1000, 100}], n];

ListPlot[{Legended[time, "Lower triangular"], 
  Legended[timeFull, "Full matrix"]}, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> All, 
 Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: May I suggest another test? How about forming the `LinearSolveFunction[]` at once from the test matrix (to separate out the LU decomposition step), and just time the application of the function to a random vector?

Comment: I get pretty much identical timings if I make the matrices more comparable by defining `rndFull[n_]:=(#+Transpose[#])&@rndLowerTriangular[n]` and using that in the full matrix test.

Comment: What about if the matrices are sparse?  Also, where do I get `RepeatedTiming`?

Comment: @fred, `RepeatedTiming` is a new function in version 10.1.