# How to know the usage of undocumented function like LinearAlgebra`BLAS?

Tags: linear-algebra, undocumented, mkl

BLAS is not documented in mathematica. Using

```
 ?LinearAlgebra`BLAS`*
```

gives

[image]

But None of the function has a detailed usage information

Click any of the function for example, `GEMM`, gives

[image]

At first I thought, BLAS in mma is belong to MKL, so I look up the usage in MKL reference manual, it says

```
call gemm ( a ,  b ,  c [ , transa ][ , transb ] [ , alpha ][ , beta ])
```

the last four parameters are all optional. But in fact, if I run

```
LinearAlgebra`BLAS`GEMM[a, b, c]
```

mma tells me, it needs 7 arguments

> LinearAlgebra`BLAS`GEMM::argrx: LinearAlgebra`BLAS`GEMM called with 3
>   arguments; 7 arguments are expected.

if I run

```
LinearAlgebra`BLAS`GEMM[a, b, c, "N", "N", 1., 0.]
```

mma tells

> LinearAlgebra`BLAS`GEMM::blnsetst: The argument a at position 1 is not
>   a string starting with one of the letters from the set NTCntc.

so the order of the arguments is not the same as MKL reference!!

**How should I know the correct order of arguments without trying several times? Are there detailed usage information of undocumented function can be found inside mma?**

**I was wondering if we could extract usage from the content of the message tag like `argrx` or `blnsetst` ?** But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I would guess "undocumented" implies an answer....

Comment: @MichaelE2 ...why they hide "undocumented" so well...

Comment: What do you expect?  Really?  We call them "internal functions" because they're not ``System` `` functions.  Their usage might change, etc.  -- Personally, I think [Oleksandr R.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99519) showed the way to those who are not adverse to work.  Perhaps it's a coincidence, but the [documentation for GEMM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/468480) indicates 7 arguments.  Someone who is truly curious would follow that up.

Comment: @MichaelE2 But as I said, the order of the argument is shuffled by mma, not the same as MKL reference. Maybe Mathematica trying its best to prevent user from using undocumented...

Comment: @MichaelE2 Hi, MichaelE2. Do you think it is possible to extract information from the message tag? If we gather all the content in the message tag, we know the usage, I don't know how to do it

Comment: "But as I said, the order of the argument is shuffled by mma" -- now you question says it, after the edit!

Comment: ``LinearAlgebra`BLAS`GEMM["N", "N", 2, a, b, 3., c]`` -- it doesn't seem that hard to figure out, given the several paradigms of the `?gemm` functions....

Comment: "How to know the usage" - trial and error, with some help from being familiar with how [the original FORTRAN routines](http://netlib.org/blas/) are invoked. I presume you'll then ask about ``LinearAlgebra`LAPACK`*`` after this?

Comment: @J.M. Well, I am just let BLAS as an example. I am actually asking the general solution. If you look into the "?LinearAlgebra`*", you can find more undocumented function, like. `XSimplex`, what is this? I have no idea. I know many guys (of course including you : ) ) on this site know the usage of many undocumented function, I am curious, how they know it?

Comment: "I am curious, how they know it?" - I already answered that question in my first comment. **Trial and error**. Why not try different permutations of the arguments until you see something that works, while letting error messages or unevaluated output guide you in choosing which permutation to do next?

Comment: @J.M. ok，i know. but for xsimplex, i even don't know what it is. how to try it?

Comment: It happens to be a simplex algorithm solver for LP problems, but why would one specifically need to know about it or use it? Especially since there are documented ways to do the same thing.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Update**

Leaving my old answer below for historical reference, however as of version 11.2.0 (currently available on Wolfram Cloud and soon to be released as a desktop product) the low-level linear algebra functions have been documented, see

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LowLevelLinearAlgebra/guide/BLASGuide.html

---

The comments by both [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) and [J. M. ♦](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) are already an excellent answer, so this is just my attempt at summarizing.

*Undocumented* means just what it says: there need not be any reference pages or usage messages, or any other kind of documentation. There are many [undocumented](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/805/what-are-some-useful-undocumented-mathematica-functions) functions and if you follow MSE regularly, you will encounter them often. Using such functionality, however, is not without its [caveats](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5940/is-using-undocumented-functionality-a-bad-idea).

Sometimes, functions (whether documented or undocumented) are written in top-level (*Mathematica*, or if you will, *Wolfram Language*) code, so one can inspect the actual implementation by [spelunking](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1742). However, that is not the case for functions implemented in C as part of the kernel.

Particularly for the `` LinearAlgebra`BLAS` `` interface, the function signatures are kept quite close to the well-established FORTRAN [conventions](http://netlib.org/blas/) (which is also what MKL adheres to, see the guide for [?gemm](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/468480)) with a few non-surprising adjustments. For instance, consider

```
xGEMM( TRANSA, TRANSB, M, N, K, ALPHA, A, LDA, B, LDB, BETA, C, LDC )
```

and the corresponding syntax for `` LinearAlgebra`BLAS`GEMM `` which is

```
GEMM[ transa, transb, alpha, a, b, beta, c ]
```

where we can see the storage-related parameters such as dimensions and [strides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206563/purpose-of-lda-argument-in-blas-dgemm) are omitted, since the kernel already knows how the matrices are laid out in memory. All other arguments are the same, and even come in the same order.

As an usage example,

```
a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}; b = {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}; c = b; (* c will be overwritten *)
LinearAlgebra`BLAS`GEMM["T", "N", -2, a, b, 1/2, c]; c

(* {{-(99/2), -57}, {-(145/2), -84}} *)

-2 Transpose[a].b + (1/2) b

(* {{-(99/2), -57}, {-(145/2), -84}} *)
```

Note that for machine precision matrices, `Dot` will end up calling the corresponding optimized `xgemm` function from MKL anyway, so I would not expect a big performance difference. It is certainly much more readable and easier to use `Dot` rather than `GEMM` for matrix multiplication.

On the topic of BLAS in *Mathematica*, I would also recommend the 2003 developer conference [talk](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/4886/) by Zbigniew Leyk, which has some further implementation details and examples.

Comment: Thank you so much! especially for providing the conference talk by Zbigniew Leyk, learned a lot. I also add a comment to Simon Woods about why `PrintDefinitions@Dot` doesn't show any trace to BLAS. Do you have any idea?

Comment: And there is a strange thing I noticed. According to the conference talk. Mathematica optimized `Dot` with BLAS. But they didn't optimize `Outer` with `BLAS`!!! The GER in BLAS can do `Outer` of two vectors with Times operation much faster than current `Outer` in mma(40 times faster I tested). Though I know `Outer` can do much more. But they should have add an internal optimized branch to this most frequent encountered case.

Comment: @matheorem The BLAS functions are implemented in C, so there are no top-level definitions that can be read. `Outer` is already optimized for `Times` and packed array input.

Comment: Odd enough. Yesterday, I use `PrintDefinitions@Dot`, and see a lot of output. But today I can only see output `Attributes[Dot] := {Flat, OneIdentity, Protected};`. Don't know which option I have triggered yesterday...

Comment: @matheorem You probably used some of the `Parallel*` functions (e.g. `LaunchKernels[]`) which do attach a few `UpValues` to `Dot`. But that has nothing to do with the actual implementation of `Dot`...

Comment: Oh, my goodness. How do you know I turned on `LaunchKernels[]`, you are amazing. BTW, I now understand `LinearAlgebra`BLAS`` as an interface mma write for C implemented BLAS, While `Dot` is actually calling C implementation directly instead of calling `LinearAlgebra`BLA``, so there is no definition shown in `PrintDefinitions`, am I right?

Answer (score 13):

**How should I know the correct order of arguments without trying several times?**

You can't, usually. A lot of the undocumented usage that you see on this site will have been worked out by trial and error. Sometimes it is fruitless - I have explored plenty of interesting-sounding internal functions and got nowhere.

**Are there detailed usage information of undocumented function can be found inside mma?**

No. "Undocumented" rather implies the absence of detailed usage information :-)

**I was wondering if we could extract usage from the content of the message tag like argrx or blnsetst?**

Sometimes the message will help, for example by stating how many or what type of argument was expected, but there is no hidden usage information. The message you see is all there is.

**Some other comments**

Sometimes you can read the function's code. For example using `PrintDefinitions`:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
PrintDefinitions[Export];
```

Sometimes you cannot read the function's code but you see it being used inside another function which you *can* read - for example `SystemException` in the previous output. This can help in working out how and why to use it.

Often the function's name is a big help. `` Image`DogVision `` is undocumented but you can probably guess what it does and that it expects an image as its argument.

Other than that it tends to be a question of how patient you are and how badly you want to know.

Comment: Why on earth **IS** ``Image`DogVision`` there at all?

Comment: @bloch, note that this is also a capability of Alpha; I guess this is the function being used behind the scenes.

Comment: Thank you very much! `PrintDefinitions` seems so useful, didn't know this before. It is a pity that `PrintDefinitions` gives nothing on ``LinearAlgebra`BLAS`GEMM``. But as ilian has answered and I also test it before. `Dot` is almost the same speed as `GEMM`, But is `Dot` really end up with calling MKL? In the output of `PrintDefinitions[Dot]`, I can't find anything related to `BLAS`. What do you think?