# Stationary solution of PDE and eigenvalues

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, finite-element-method

I need to find the eigenvalues of the stationary solution ($\dot{u}=0$) of the following PDE

$
\dot{u}=-d u + (d-2)x u'-v(d)L_{d}^{1}(u'+2x u'')
$
with
$
L_{d}^{n}(f)=\int_0^\infty dy~y^{-1+d/2}\left(\frac{-2 a(1+y)e^{-y}}{ f + y + a e^{-y}}\right)
$

where $\partial_t f =\dot{f}$, $\partial_x f = f'$, $d=3$ and $a$ is a parameter, now set to $a=1$. Finally, $v(d)$ is a dimension dependent parameter, to be defined later. We need two initial conditions to solve the resulting equation but the two are not independent, if we set $u'(0) = m^2$, then $u(0)= - \frac{v(d)}{d} L_{d}^{1}(m^2)$. We are not done yet, because we need to vary $m^2$ to find the true solution. For a general value of $m^2$, the solution $u^*(x)$ is going to diverge at a finite value of $x$. As $m^2$ gets closer to its 'true' value, $u^*(x)$ diverges at higher and higher $x$. I find the 'true' values of $m^2$ by dichotomy (plot the solutions and change $m^2$ accordingly) and then if i found the correct $m^2$ say, for up to 4 digits of precision, then i can look for the eigenvalues.  I have two questions:

- Is there an elegant way to find the correct $m^2$?
- Is there a more efficient way to do this, than my implementation? Or maybe one that can easily be generalized for coupled PDE-s.

```
Clear[intL, v];
v[d_] := (2^(d + 1) \[Pi]^(d/2) Gamma[d/2])^-1
intL[d_, n_, \[Alpha]_?NumericQ][func_?NumericQ] := 
 intL[d, n, \[Alpha]][
   func] = -2 \[Alpha] NIntegrate[
    y^(d/2 - 1) ( E^-y (1 + y)  (y + E^-y \[Alpha] + func)^-n), {y, 
     0, \[Infinity]}, 
    Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}]
statEQ[d_, \[Alpha]_][r_] := -d u[r] + (d - 2) r u'[r] - 
  v[d] intL[d, 1, \[Alpha]][u'[r] + 2 r  u''[r]]
Clear[rStart, rEnd, bc, psol, m2, alpha];
rStart = 10^-6; rEnd = 2; alpha = 1; dim = 3;
bc = {u[rStart] == -(1/(24 \[Pi]^2)) intL[dim, 1, alpha][m2], 
   u'[rStart] == m2};
psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{statEQ[dim, alpha][\[Rho]] == 0, bc}, 
   u, {\[Rho], rStart, rEnd}, {m2}, 
   Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual", 
     "ParametricCaching" -> None, "ParametricSensitivity" -> None}];
```

(I can't directly give the initial conditions at x=0, so I chose a small rStart) Findig a good enough $m^2$ by dichotomy:

```
mIni = -0.2648;
fsol = psol[mIni]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*Plot[Evaluate[fsol[rho]],{rho,rStart,rEnd},PlotRange\[Rule]All]*)
```

Finally, obtaining the eigenvalues:

```
(Derivative[1]@intL[d_, n_, \[Alpha]_])[
  func_] := (Derivative[1]@intL[d, n, \[Alpha]])[
   func] = -n intL[d, n + 1, \[Alpha]][func]
linearizedDE = 
  Coefficient[
    Series[statEQ[dim, alpha][\[Rho]] /. {u[\[Rho]_] :> 
        u[\[Rho]] + \[Epsilon] \[Delta]u[\[Rho]], (Derivative[n_]@
           u)[\[Rho]_] :> (Derivative[n]@
            u)[\[Rho]] + \[Epsilon] (Derivative[
              n]@\[Delta]u)[\[Rho]]}, {\[Epsilon], 0, 
      1}], \[Epsilon]] /. u -> fsol;
linEnd = 1;
{om, nu} = 
   NDEigenvalues[
    linearizedDE, \[Delta]u[\[Rho]], {\[Rho], rStart, linEnd}, 2, 
    Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
        "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> (linEnd - rStart)/
           10^3 }}}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: This is not PDE, this is integrodifferential equation. Your problem is not state clear. What is domain for solution of you equation? Is it `{t,0,Infinity}, {x,0,2}`? What do you try to minimize with respect to `m`?

Comment: In principle the domain is {t,0,Infinity}, {x,0,Infinity}. By fine tuning the parameter m^2 we can increase the range {x,0, something(m^2) }, where you can obtain a solution where the function u does not diverge. If I set a high rEnd, the ndsolve will signal, that the system became stiff.  In that sense, you do not minimize anything w.r.t m^2, you need to fine tune it.

Comment: What do you expecting at `x->Infinity`? Is it zero or some limited value?

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know, how u should behave in the limit x - > Infinity. I do know however, that u=0 at some value x_0 and this x_0 increases as m^2 is tuned. In fact i have tried FindRoot[psol[m2] [x_0], {m2, - 0.1}] for a large value of x_0 to find a good enough m^2,but it did not work.

Comment: But `intL[3, 1, 1][0]` exists, therefore there is limited value at infinity `u=-v[3]/3 intL[3, 1, 1][0]=0.0102017`. Then we can normalize solution so that `u->0` at infinity and use  2 conditions `u[0]=-0.0102017` and `u'[rEnd]=0` with `rEend=10` for example in numerical computation.

Comment: Yes, it can be done definitely.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you solution. First is about `rEnd=2`. Where you take this range? Second is about `linEnd = 1`. Why did you take this range less then `rEnd`? And final question is about `mIni = -0.2648`. Is this value been taken only because you try to reproduce eigenvalues   -1.524 and 0.648? It looks like some kind of play with unknown rules. Then how we can answer your question? :)

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough. So: with a given value of mIni, the solution fsol becomes stiff or singular at some x. Then mIni is tuned to increase this x as much as possible. So I choose rEnd sufficiently high, to be able to see this x value and simply set linEnd to be slightly smaller or equal to this x. As this x approaches a sufficiently high value, the eigenvalues nu and om approach an asymptotic value. For example if I tune x as large as possible with 4 digits of precision in mIni, then I expect om and nu to be precise up to 4 digits of precision. In this sense the only unkown is mIni.

Comment: Did you pay attention that `intL[3,1,1][f]` also has singular point at about `f=-1` and then highly oscillates at `f<-1`?

Comment: Yes, only this cause the system to become stiff or singular. Thanks for pointing out, this gave me the idea to stop the ndsolve, when the denominator of the integral intL become small.

Comment: Not denominator, but  parameter `func` becomes close to -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is exact solution of stationary problem `u=-v[3]/3 intL[3, 1, 1][0]=0.0102017`, therefore we can consider eigensystem around this solution as follows

```
Clear[intL, v];
v[d_] := (2^(d + 1) \[Pi]^(d/2) Gamma[d/2])^-1
intL[d_, n_, \[Alpha]_?NumericQ][func_?NumericQ] := 
 intL[d, n, \[Alpha]][
   func] = -2 \[Alpha] NIntegrate[
    y^(d/2 - 1) (E^-y (1 + y) (y + E^-y \[Alpha] + func)^-n), {y, 
     0, \[Infinity]}, 
    Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}]
statEQ[d_, \[Alpha]_][r_] := -d u[r] + (d - 2) r u'[r] - 
  v[d] intL[d, 1, \[Alpha]][u'[r] + 2 r u''[r]]
Clear[rStart, rEnd, bc, psol, m2, alpha];
rStart = 10^-6; rEnd = 10; alpha = 1; dim = 3;
bc = {u[rStart] == 0.010201726677643571, u'[rStart] == 0};
sol = NDSolveValue[{statEQ[dim, alpha][\[Rho]] == 0, bc}, 
   u, {\[Rho], rStart, rEnd}];
 (Derivative[1]@intL[d_, n_, \[Alpha]_])[
  func_] := (Derivative[1]@intL[d, n, \[Alpha]])[
   func] = -n intL[d, n + 1, \[Alpha]][func]
linearizedDE = 
  Coefficient[
    Series[statEQ[dim, alpha][\[Rho]] /. {u[\[Rho]_] :> 
        u[\[Rho]] + \[Epsilon] \[Delta]u[\[Rho]], (Derivative[n_]@
           u)[\[Rho]_] :> (Derivative[n]@
            u)[\[Rho]] + \[Epsilon] (Derivative[
              n]@\[Delta]u)[\[Rho]]}, {\[Epsilon], 0, 
      1}], \[Epsilon]] /. u -> sol;
linEnd = 10;
{om, nu} = 
   NDEigensystem[{linearizedDE, 
     DirichletCondition[\[Delta]u[\[Rho]] == 0, 
      True]}, \[Delta]u[\[Rho]], {\[Rho], rStart, linEnd}, 
    10]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Note, that we can take `rEnd, linEnd` arbitrary in this case. Visualization

```
Table[Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[nu[[i]]]], {\[Rho], rStart, linEnd}, 
  PlotLabel -> om[[i]], PlotRange -> All], {i, 10}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Also we can compute solution of bouncing type. Since `intL[3,1,1][f]` has singular point at `f=-1` we can suppose that there is a critical point solution we detect with `WhenEvent[]` as follows

```
v[d_] := (2^(d + 1) \[Pi]^(d/2) Gamma[d/2])^-1
intL[d_, n_, \[Alpha]_?NumericQ][func_?NumericQ] := 
 intL[d, n, \[Alpha]][
   func] = -2 \[Alpha] NIntegrate[
     y^(d/2 - 1) (E^-y (1 + y) (y + E^-y \[Alpha] + func)^-n), {y, 
      0, \[Infinity]}, 
     Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}] // Quiet
statEQ[d_, \[Alpha]_][r_] := -d u0[r] + (d - 2) r u0'[r] - 
  v[d] intL[d, 1, \[Alpha]][u0'[r] + 2 r u0''[r]]
rStart = 0; rEnd = 3.97; alpha = 1; d = 3; dim = 3;

r0 = 10^-6; m = -0.2648; eq = {-d u0[r] + (d - 2) r u0'[r] - 
    v[d] intL[d, 1, 1][u0'[r] + 2 r u0''[r]] == 0}; nds = 
 NDSolveValue[{eq, 
   u0'[r0] == m, -d u0[r0] - v[d] intL[d, 1, 1][u0'[r0]] == 0, 
   WhenEvent[u0[r] == 0, {rc = r, u0'[r] -> -u0'[r]}]}, 
  u0, {r, r0, rEnd}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}, 
  MaxSteps -> Infinity]
```

We plot this solution and `f=u0'[r] + 2 r u0''[r]` to show that solution passes point `f=-1` and problem becomes stuff at `r > rEnd`

```
{Plot[nds[r],{r, r0, rEnd}, PlotRange -> All],
Plot[nds'[r] + 2 r nds''[r], {r, r0, rEnd}, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

Now we have position of the critical point `rc=1.03115` therefore we can compute eigensystem in a range `r0 <= r <=rc`

```
(Derivative[1]@intL[d_, n_, \[Alpha]_])[
  func_] := (Derivative[1]@intL[d, n, \[Alpha]])[
   func] = -n intL[d, n + 1, \[Alpha]][func]
linearizedDE = 
  Coefficient[
    Series[statEQ[dim, alpha][\[Rho]] /. {u0[\[Rho]_] :> 
        u0[\[Rho]] + \[Epsilon] \[Delta]u[\[Rho]], (Derivative[n_]@
           u0)[\[Rho]_] :> (Derivative[n]@
            u0)[\[Rho]] + \[Epsilon] (Derivative[
              n]@\[Delta]u)[\[Rho]]}, {\[Epsilon], 0, 
      1}], \[Epsilon]] /. u0 -> nds;
linEnd = rc; NDEigenvalues[linearizedDE, \[Delta]u[\[Rho]], {\[Rho], rStart, 
  linEnd}, 2, 
 Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> (linEnd - rStart)/10^2}}}]
```

Finally we got eigenvalues `{0.636452, -1.52897}`, and the question is how we can optimize initial value `m`. The answer depends on physics of this problem, for instance, we can make suggestion about minimum of potential in a critical point.

Comment: It does not seem to be correct to give u'[rStart]=0 as initial condition. The function sol in your answer is a consant function (which is indeed a stationary solution but I'm looking for the non-trivial one) and therefore the eigenvalues are not correct either. The resulting u function has to be something like fsol in my question and the first two eigenvalues om and nu are also the correct (or very close to the correct) ones in my question.

Comment: @dzsoga What do you mean under nontrivial? If solution is unique, then there is only one solution  `u=-v[3]/3 intL[3, 1, 1][0]=0.0102017` not diverges at `x->Infinity`. If solution not unique then there are many solutions non restricted at `x->Infinity` and therefore your problem not defined well. Hence you need to define the problem so that the solution is unique. Your own solution diverges at `x->Infinity`.

Comment: The function u here is a thermodynamic potential. The t variable the reduced temperature. You are right, the PDE for it has multiple stationary solutions. In fact it has two. The solutions are distinguished by their eigenvalues(critical exponents). The nontrivial u solution corresponds to a second order phase transition. Please observe, how my fsol changes as mIni is changed.

Comment: @dzsoga How did you derive this equation?

Comment: It is the Wetterich equation for a Z_2 symmetric scalar model (which happens to be in the Ising universality class) at the Local Potential Approximation of the effective action.

Comment: @dzsoga Please, see update to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your update. It is not a matter of accuracy however. The first two eigenvalues should (known to) be -1.524 and 0.648 (as can be seen from om and nu, when my code is ran).  An equivalent rephrasing of the BC in my question is something like  u'[potmin]=0 and normalize u so that u[potmin]=0. In this case one has to finetune the position potmin rather than m^2. I will have more computer time from tuesday. I will also add an answer then.

Comment: @dzsoga How you know that two eigenvalues should  be -1.524 and 0.648? Is it from some paper?

Comment: Yes. The negative one is -1/nu, where nu is the critical exponent of the correlation length, and the second one is the first subleading correction to the scaleing of the correlation length. This is a leading order prediction. These exponents, or the nontrivial fixed point can be obtained by an other method: if you consider u(x) to be a polynomial and you can decompose the PDE to a set of coupled ODEs for the coefficients of this polynomial function. E.g. I used this in my question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/229458/67601

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to use the domain option of the interpolation function obtained from the ndsolve. Here I set a very large value rEnd. rEnd is arbitrary, but has to be sufficiently large.

```
rootEq[\[Alpha]_, mass2_?NumericQ] := 
  Block[{paramSol, rhoend, rStart, rEnd, alpha, dim, fsol, delta},
   delta = 10^-6;
   rStart = delta; rEnd = 10; alpha = \[Alpha]; dim = 3;
   paramSol = 
    ParametricNDSolveValue[{statEQ[dim, alpha][\[Rho]] == 0, bc}, 
     u, {\[Rho], rStart, rEnd}, {m2},
     Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual", 
       "ParametricCaching" -> None, "ParametricSensitivity" -> None}];
   fsol = Quiet@paramSol[mass2];
   Return[fsol["Domain"][[1, 2]]];
   ];
```

One then can visualize the end r*, where the solution of the differential equation becomes stiff:

```
dat = ParallelTable[{mass,rootEq[1,mass]}, {mass, -0.200, -0.300, -0.005}]; 
ListPlot[dat]
```

[image]

The x axis shows the parameter m^2, while the y axis shows the corresponding r*. As you can see, this is a quite narrow resonance curve, and $r* \to \infty$ as the corresponding $m^2_*$ is approached.

Using the function rootEq, one can simply use findroot, such as

```
bignumber=10;
FindRoot[rootEq[1, mass2] == bignumber, {mass2, mIni} ]
```

The idea is that a more precise $m^2$ corresponds to a larger $r*$. This method, with the current precision settings (basic machine precision everywhere) breaks down at around $r^*=1.8$ (corresponding to $m^2 = -0.264812$). As the workingprecison, precisiongoal and accuracygoal are increased, we can approach a higher $r^*$ using this findroot method. But now, I came across a nother problem. The eigenvalues I was looking for (and obtained from NDEigenvalues) are more sensitive to the MaxCellMeasure option, than the precision of $m^2$ beyond the 4th digit of precision... :D

Comment: Ok! It is a nice approach (+1). Probably we can also use physical reasons to solve this problem.